# Recolección inicial de preguntas para la elección de los moderadores

Tags: discusión, elecciones

Nuestra comunidad está a punto de comenzar sus elecciones [la semana del 17 de julio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/election/1). En conexión con eso, tendremos un tiempo de preguntas y respuestas con los candidatos. Esta será una oportunidad para que los miembros de la comunidad formulen preguntas para los candidatos sobre el tema de la moderación. La participación en cualquier parte de este proceso es completamente voluntaria.

Así es cómo esto funcionará:

- Permitiremos sugerencias de preguntas a los candidatos en este hilo hasta la fecha de inicio de la fase de nominaciones, que es el lunes 17 de julio a las 20:00 UTC o 15:00 EST (dennos algunos momentos en lo que tardamos en entrar para cerrarlo - este proceso es manual). Publiquen respuestas aquí que contengan cualquier pregunta que ustedes quieran que los candidatos contesten. Por favor publiquen *una pregunta por cada respuesta*.
- Actuando en mi rol de gerente de esta comunidad, proporcionaré una selección corta de preguntas. Las primeras dos están garantizadas de estar en el cuestionario final y las demás se usarán solamente si no hay suficientes preguntas comunitarias.
- Si tu pregunta contiene un enlace, por favor usa el formato `[texto](enlace)`. Esto nos ayudará a poder copiar tu aportación fácilmente al cuestionario final.
- Este es el mejor momento de llamar la atención sobre cuestiones especificas y de preguntar sobre los asuntos que estamos viviendo en nuestra comunidad. ¿Cómo se enfrentarán los nuevos moderadores a estas situaciones? Pregúntenles.
- Al empezar nuestra fase de nominaciones, seleccionaré **hasta 8 de las preguntas más votadas por la comunidad** en este hilo y las usaré en combinación con las dos que yo entregaré. Reservo un poco de control editorial en la selección de preguntas y tengo también el derecho de no seleccionar cualquier pregunta (sin importar cuantos votos tenga) que no trate de (1) el tema de la moderación del sitio (2) la elección o (3) preguntas irrelevantes. Dicho esto, si tengo problema con alguna pregunta por no ser lo suficientemente clara, dejaré comentarios para que el autor pueda editar su aportación antes de la selección final de las preguntas.
- Estando seleccionadas las preguntas finales, una nueva pregunta se abrirá en el Meta para contener la lista para los candidatos.  Típicamente, esta lista tendrá 10 preguntas en total.
- Nótese que esta no es la única manera de obtener información sobre los candidatos.  Se vale, por ejemplo, el tener una sesión de chat con ellos para preguntar cosas adicionales o tal vez para aclarar lo que se ha presentado.

Si hay preguntas sobre este proceso, por favor comenten aquí.

**Se espera una pregunta por cada respuesta. La única excepción es la primera respuesta (la mía) siendo que tengo que dar las 2 preguntas oficiales y otros ejemplos.**

---

El [cuestionario oficial está aquí](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2478/2017-elecci%C3%B3n-de-moderador-cuestionario). Ya no estamos aceptando preguntas nuevas.

Comment: ¿Podemos comentar las preguntas propuestas para solicitar aclaraciones o sugerir mejoras? Lo pregunto porque no está en las reglas.

Comment: @toledano para mi era obvio que sí, pero ahora que lo dices, me surge la duda. Me pregunto ¿ser valiente complicaría lo que se va a hacer con lo que se está solicitando? Me respondo, no, al contrario. Conclusión. Solicita las aclaraciones y sugiere las mejoras que consideres oportunas para contar con buenas preguntas que ayuden a que la elección se lleve de la mejor manera.

Comment: Pues ya lo estoy haciendo...

Comment: Supongo que el recuento sera solo de votos positivos

Answer (score 19):

Mi pregunta es sencilla, pero es una pregunta a la que yo mismo no tengo respuesta:

- ¿Qué criterios sigues para moderar preguntas de tecnologías de las que no tienes conocimientos?

Answer (score 19):

¿Para ti es un dilema la retención de usuarios vs. contenido de calidad?

Es decir, ante la pregunta de un usuario nuevo que tiene alguna deficiencia (causal de cierre) prefieres<sup>1</sup>:

1. Ser permisivo para contribuir a su retención como usuario cotidiano
2. Ser estricto para contribuir con la calidad del contenido de la comunidad

¿Tienes alguna alternativa ante este *"dilema"*?

---

<sup>**1**</sup> Me refiero a que la pregunta tiene alguna presunta deficiencia.

Comment: Excelente pregunta y, a quien responda, le recomendaría revisar muchas de las publicaciones de Meta y citarlas como ejemplo, especialmente aquellas con muchísimos comentarios.

Answer (score 15):

¿Qué aportes o mejoras esperas ver en el sitio una vez dejes de ser moderador? O dicho de otra forma, ¿Cuál es la visión que tienes del sitio  cuando termine tu periodo de moderación?

Comment: Esta es muy buena! La idea es dejar el sitio mejor de como lo tomamos.

Answer (score 13):

Un moderador es un usuario normal al que se le dan una serie de herramientas adicionales. Por tanto, las tareas de edición, comentar, cerrar y abrir preguntas, etc es algo que sigue pudiendo hacer. Sin embargo, también puede contactar con los usuarios de forma privada, administrar etiquetas, juntar preguntas, interactuar con otros moderadores (del mismo sitio o de otros), perseguir a los empleados de Stack Exchange para conseguir nuevas funcionalidades para tu sitio...

Teniendo todo esto en cuenta, ¿en qué te gustaría  invertir la mayor parte de su tiempo como moderador y con qué finalidad? Esboza tu idea de qué podría definirse como éxito al realizar tal labor.

Answer (score 13):

Identifica un problema de SOes en el que te gustaría trabajar como moderador. ¿Cómo usarías tus superpoderes para ayudar a resolverlo?

Comment: Creo que esta pregunta tiene  mucho pontencial, pero me gustaria que se cambiara a: `El mayor problema de SOes`

Comment: la razón por la que no lo hice (pese a que fue [la sugerencia de Picoh](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38686373#38686373)) es porque el mayor problema puede no ser solucionable como moderador. Si un candidato entiende que el mayor problema es que no mucha gente usa SOes, no hay poder de mod que ayude a solucionarlo. Capaz que debería ser "identifica el mayor problema en el que un mod tenga incidencia"

Comment: Es muy buena pregunta. Y, si bien no están preguntando lo mismo, sólo me temo que se termine respondiendo igual que a la pregunta [¿en qué te gustaría invertir la mayor parte de su tiempo?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2393/127)

Comment: @Mariano si eso pasa, también habla del candidato, y a mi por lo menos me daría herramientas para decidir por quién votar :D

Answer (score 11):

¿Cómo te sienta sentirte *escudriñado* constantemente en el chat y en Meta por las decisiones que tomes y tener que dar explicaciones sobre ellas?

Comment: ¿Podrían separarse? Le di un voto a toda esta respuesta,  porque la segunda pregunta que planteas me parecio muy buena, y tambien mucho mejor que la primera. (Porque la primera podría responderse con si o no). Me gustaria solo votar la segunda.

Comment: @Kenny: La forma en que respondan los postulantes nos va ayudar a tomar la decisión. Yo preferiría a un postulante que de respuestas mas allá que un "Sí" o un "No" sin "perderse entre las ramas".

Comment: @Rubén si, apoyo eso. Quizas me falto agregar que me parece que las preguntas son bastante diferentes entre una y otra. Me imagino que algunos votaron más por la segunda que por la primera.

Comment: @Kenny: No sé los demás, pero yo no, posiblemente porque "me ha tocado" participar (a veces sólo como observador) en conversaciones en el [chat] y Meta donde se "escudriña" a los moderadores ♦.

Comment: Me parece que con esta edición quedo mucho mejor

Comment: Quedo excelente, gracias fedorqui.

Comment: @Kenny gracias por sugerir los cambios :) Perdona que no contestara ayer, edité desde el móvil y contestar comentarios por allí siempre me cuesta.

Comment: No hay problema. :D

Answer (score 7):

Las preguntas básicas que se pueden resolver con una búsqueda de unos pocos minutos en un buscador de Internet.. ¿hacen bajar la calidad del sitio?

Comment: IMO, la respuesta depende mucho de lo que se entienda por "calidad del sitio" (algo que parece carecer de consenso). Quiza se puede hacer mas nutritiva la respuesta pidiendo que se aclare como el candidato entiende/define **la calidad del sitio**.

Answer (score 7):

Constantemente muchas publicaciones son eliminadas o marcadas como *muy baja calidad*, y muchas terminan en la cola de revisión de moderador (por ejemplo, las "*revisiones de baja calidad disputadas*"). ¿Cómo definirías, con tus propias palabras, el límite entre las preguntas que eliminarías y las que conservarías?

Comment: Sé que estoy agregando la pregunta bastante tarde (tuve una semana complicada), pero creo que algo así sería importante de agregar en el cuestionario.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo. Es pregunta típica y clásica que representa el 80% del trabajo de un moderador.

Comment: Además de fijar un parámetro sobre la experiencia de qué es baja calidad y cómo se ajusta a las vicisitudes de SOes, algo en lo que observo bastante heterogeneidad

Answer (score 6):

¿Qué cosas te desmotivarían a seguir moderando?

Answer (score 6):

Con base en esta pregunta [¿Se debería usar jQuery en “toda” aplicación HTML/CSS/JavaScript?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/82254/6635).

Considerando la forma en la que se formuló (recién publicada) [¿Se debería usar jQuery en toda aplicación HTML/CSS/JavaScript?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/82254/1)

Algunos la consideran **basada en opiniones** y otros que **es objetiva**.

**¿Cómo actuarías ante este tipo de preguntas?**

Comment: Este es un excelente caso y pregunta para los futuros moderadores. Me causo mucha confusión esta pregunta del sitio. Ojala recibas más votos.

Answer (score 6):

Cuando hay un problema en la comunidad que no está marcado (Al menos claramente) en las reglas del sitio

**¿A quién le pides ayuda?** para saber como responder a la situación

Comment: Es una buena pregunta. pero espero que las respuestas no recurran a frases trilladas, "de manual", que respondan lo obvio sin mostrar mucha experiencia en la gestión de estos casos.

Answer (score 6):

<sub>Extraída de las [recientes elecciones de Travel](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4318/6997):</sub>

De la actual gestión de la moderación de este sitio, ¿qué tienes intención de cambiar, mejorar y mantener como está?

Comment: Creo que se puede solapar un poco con la pregunta [Identifica un problema de SOes en el que te gustaría trabajar como moderador](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2396/127)... No preguntan lo mismo, pero las respuestas sí podrían estar repitiéndose.

Comment: @Mariano cierto. Bueno, esta ya no saldrá con el último voto negativo... ojalá la otra sí (tiene todos los números) y veamos respuestas jugosas.

Answer (score 5):

Aquí les dejo una lista general de preguntas favoritas recolectadas de diferentes elecciones de nuestra red. Como mencioné en las instrucciones anteriores, las primeras dos están garantizadas de aparecer en el cuestionario final. Si al terminar esta semana no tenemos por lo menos 8 preguntas comunitarias, usaré algunas más de esta lista para llenar los espacios.

Si les gusta una de las otras preguntas propuestas aquí, las pueden usar tal y como las ven o las pueden modificar si bien les parece. Recuerden que queremos ver **una pregunta por cada respuesta**.

---

**Mis preguntas a los candidatos:**

- ¿Cómo tratarías a un usuario que produce una corriente estable de respuestas valiosas pero que tiende a generar una cantidad grande de argumentos/reportes de los comentarios?
- ¿Cómo enfrentarías una situación en la que otro moderador cerró/eliminó/etc una pregunta que no crees que lo debía ser?

**Preguntas adicionales:**

- ¿En tú opinion, que es lo que hacen los moderadores?
- Un diamante se pondrá en cada comentario, pregunta, y respuesta que hayas hecho en el pasado. Todo lo que has hecho se verá bajo una luz diferente.  ¿Cómo te hace sentir eso?
- ¿En que forma piensas que el ser moderador te hará más efectivo al contrario que simplemente llegar a 10k o 20k puntos de reputación?

Answer (score 5):

Una clásica:

> Se hace una pregunta que recibe muy buenas respuestas. Luego el autor
>   marca la pregunta y pide que se borre porque le causaría problemas en
>   el trabajo o la academia. ¿Qué haces?

Comment: muy buena pregunta

Comment: Quizás me equivoque, pero tengo la impresión de que esto se responde directamente de la ayuda, o incluso pegando la respuesta a preguntas ya realizadas en Meta.

Answer (score 5):

¿Que harias si un usuario te acusa de abusar de tus privilegios como moderador?

Answer (score 5):

¿Cuánto tiempo de tu día **planeas** dedicarle a moderar en SOes? y ¿En qué huso horario estarías más activo?

Comment: Esperaría que esto esté en la presentación de la nominación, por lo que no creo que haga falta agregar en el cuestionario.

Answer (score 4):

*Teniendo en cuenta que estas preguntas son abiertas a opiniones de cada candidato, y como tal cualquier respuesta es válida, quisiera preguntar algo como esto:*

¿Cómo lidiarías antes los insultos o bien conversaciones que puedan tornarse turbulentas?

Comment: Esta y [esta otra](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2408/638) son muy parecidas, casi la misma. Prefiero esta porque es va directo al punto.

Comment: [Otra](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2420/65) que se parece.

Answer (score 4):

Que es lo que se deberia priorizar, arreglar la pregunta y dejarla bonita o indicarle a OP que cosas podria hacer para arreglar su propia pregunta y que esta ademas de bonita sea buena?

Comment: Jaja, acabas de exponer tu día a día en el sitio :P

Answer (score 3):

¿Cómo lidiarías con usuarios bromistas tanto en SOes como en Meta?

Answer (score 3):

¿Qué características consideras de un buen moderador? Mencionar unas 4 a 5 de ellas.

Answer (score 2):

Que modo de acción te parece mas adecuado para un moderador ♦? Usar las herramientas de moderación solo en los casos indispensables que no pueda resolver la comunidad por si misma o ser mucho mas proactivo y tratar de actuar sobre el máximo de ámbitos del sitio para tratar que las preguntas y respuestas sean de la máxima calidad posible?

Me interesa mucho la explicación de porque elegirías una u otra.

Comment: tu pregunta se parece a [la de fedorqui](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2393/15855)

Answer (score 2):

¿Cómo actuarías si no te alcanza el tiempo para moderar?

Comment: ¿Cómo se sabe cuanto tiempo se necesita para moderar?

Comment: @Rubén pues mira a los moderadores de ahora y a Miquel (sin desprestigiar la buena labor que hizo cuando estaba activo).

Comment: Mejor les pregunto. En tu opinión ¿Cuánto es el tiempo mínimo requerido que un moderador de la comunidad debía dedicarle? Mejor publico una pregunta.

Comment: @rubén, podría ¿cuánto tiempo (diario/semanal) te comprometes a dedicar a moderar la comunidad? Como una promesa de campaña.

Comment: @toledano: Esa sería otra pregunta, similar, más no "posible duplicado" de esta.

Comment: Me parece muy buena esta pregunta

Answer (score 2):

¿Actuarías de moderador en una pregunta/respuesta que necesita moderación en que has participado anteriormente en calidad de usuario normal?

Answer (score 2):

Si te llega un reporte y notas que se debe a una disputa entre dos o más usuarios, tomando en cuenta que los usuarios se insultan, amedrentan y se agreguen mutuamente:

- ¿Cuál sería tu postura?
- ¿Qué acciones tomarías para mediar la disputa?
- ¿Cómo resolverías el conflicto?

Comment: Otras preguntas relacionadas 1. https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2408/65 2. https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2407/65

Answer (score 2):

[De las elecciones de SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/351978/1983854):

¿Tienes alguna publicación en Meta de la que te sientas especialmente orgulloso o que muestre tu filosofía sobre la moderación?

Comment: Esta debería haber tenido más votos. La participación en Meta, la elocuencia, el conocimiento de las herramientas de SE y el trato con otros usuarios es importante,

Comment: @Mariano sí. Llegó tarde mi respuesta y quedó abajo (y bueno, no gustó demasiado a tenor de los votos negativos). Lo ideal sería un equpo de moderadores coral, con alguno experimentado y otro más nuevo para que al menos alguien conozca las herramientas con profundidad.

Answer (score 1):

Si te "invitaran" a una fiesta de disfraces de super héroes a la que no puedes faltar, responde lo siguiente indicando el qué y el por qué.

1. ¿Cuál es tu super poder favorito?
2. ¿De qué super héroe te disfrazarías?

Comment: Que mal por esos downvoters

Comment: @jasilva no he votado negativamente esta respuesta, pero tengo curiosidad: ¿es una pregunta válida para la elección de los candidatos?

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave Solo pienso que no todo en la vida es cuadrado, si estamos en SOes a veces tambien es por diversión. Y a esta pregunta no le dieron oportunidad :( ... recuerdo que en alguna escuesta de SO venia algo parecido, como Star Wars vs Star Trek o algo asi. Y si los mismisimos fundadores de SO mandaron esa pregunta, ¿por qué esta de rubén tendria que considerarse "mala"?

Comment: @jasilva, voto a favor de la respuesta de Rubén, vamos a ver si alguien mas se anima, por qué no :)

Comment: A mi esta pregunta me encantó. Nuestros superhéroes favoritos y sobretodo el que elegimos como avatar hablan de como nos vemos a nosotros mismos y de los valores con los que nos sentimos identificados. Son pruebas de personalidad, que son muy pertinentes en este tipo de ejercicios. Tal vez faltó aclarar el objetivo.

Comment: @toledano: Considero que tienes razón, hubiera sido bueno que le agregara mas detalles para que estuviera claro el motivo de una pregunta de este tipo.

Comment: @JuanM por favor no olvides esta pregunta que es sencillamente la más votada de todas las presentadas (11 positivos y 10 negativos = 21 votos) y tiene suficientes votos positivos para estar en el cuestionario.

Comment: @toledano segun mis calculos al cierre es la pregunta 8 con 12 votos en este momento

Answer (score 0):

¿Qué decisiones de un moderador te hacen pensar que su labor no es la mejor para el sitio? Menciona 4 a 5 actitudes de este tipo.

Answer (score 0):

> 2. Como moderador ¿si encuentras una pregunta o respuesta que tu sabes y
>      tienes evidencia que proviene de otra fuente, qué harías con el
>      usuario y la pregunta/respuesta?.

*Con base al [comentario de Rubén](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2390/la-recolecci%C3%B3n-inicial-de-preguntas-para-la-elecci%C3%B3n-de-los-moderadores/2427#comment7425_2418)*

Comment: Parece que no se entiende la idea. El plagio simplemente está prohibido en el sitio. Si un moderador deja pasar cosas como esta, entonces debería considerar su labor nuevamente.

Answer (score 0):

La típica de ¿Por qué crees que serás un buen moderador? o dicho de otra manera ¿Qué crees que puedes aportar al sitio como moderador?

Answer (score 0):

Si fueres elegido como moderador, te tomarías el tiempo de seguir respondiendo preguntas? o te limitarías a solo checar el sitio.

Answer (score -1):

¿Cuál sería tu postura con respecto a una publicación en Meta que contradice a un artículo de ayuda oficial?

Para clarificar considera el siguiente caso hipotético:

En https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging se indica que se debe evitar el uso de etiquetas en los títulos, sin embargo, un usuario con reputación +5 000 publica en Meta una pregunta autorespondida en la que sugiere que se incluyan etiquetas en los títulos.

Answer (score -1):

¿Qué cualidades crees que debe tener un buen moderador y cuáles de ellas tú posees?

Comment: Esta pregunta ya se hizo y tiene votos: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2403/638

Answer (score -3):

Uno de los pilares de nuestro modelo está de descrito en [Compórtate bien](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice). Sin mencionar nombres menciona dos situaciones que hayas observado en el sitio en los que se haya faltado a lo indicado en el artículo referido y las acciones realizadas en favor de la comunidad. Por último menciona si tu hubieras hecho lo mismo o actuado diferente y la razón de esto.

Comment: Creo que esta pregunta [ya está planteada](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2407/638) con tres minutos de antelación.

Comment: @toledano: Son similares más no tanto como para marcarlas como "posibles duplicados" (si se pudiera)

Comment: Hay otra  [pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2420/65) que también es similar más no idéntica.

Answer (score -3):

¿En que forma piensas que el ser moderador te hará más efectivo al contrario que simplemente llegar a 10k o 20k puntos de reputación?

Answer (score -3):

> 1. ¿Has revisado las preguntas y respuestas publicadas **antes de la
>      graduación de Stack Overflow en Español** y qué tienes en mente algún plan de acción?

Answer (score -5):

¿Como manejarias a un usuario con poder (moderador diamantado o empleado de SO) que actua de forma contraria a sus propias normas?

Comment: @toledano La pregunta de Juan es relativa a cómo coordinarse entre moderadores. Que haya desacuerdo no implica ningún incumplimiento de normas. La mia es relativa a un moderador o empleado que abusa de su privilegio.

Comment: DivideByZeroException

Comment: @EmanuelVe [Time to take a stand](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342440/time-to-take-a-stand)

Answer (score -5):

¿Qué propones para prevenir el plagio? ¿Qué harías en caso de que ocurra? ¿actuarías diferente en caso de que fuera un usuario nuevo o alguno experimentado?

Artículo de ayuda relacionado [¿Cómo referir material de otros?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/referencing)

Comment: El plagio no se puede prevenir. Va a suceder. La pregunta sería solo lo segundo, y en realidad eso está cubierto directamente en los lineamientos de StackOverflow en general: no se permite el plagio. Cuando se demuestra que se ha cometido plagio en una publicación en otros sitios, el moderador la elimina. Si un moderador hace distinto, creería que está en falta con su labor como moderador.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: Las preguntas son para los postulados. Al responder te estas adelantando. Si tu comentario es una propuesta de mejora, pues no entiendo.

Comment: Es porque esta pregunta no debería ser para los postulandos. Es como preguntar si permitirías que una pregunta que no se entiende pueda permanecer abierta o esperar a que tenga los 5 votos de cierre.

Comment: Pues obviamente discrepo. Si no te gusta, vota negativo,

Comment: Por cierto, googlea prevenir plagio

Comment: Claro, de haberlo sabido ya estaría implementado en el sitio ;). Pero dejemos eso aquí. (Y no googleo, mi buscador principal es otro)

Comment: @Rubén, yo lo cambiaría a: _Como moderador ¿si encuentras una pregunta o respuesta que tu sabes y tienes evidencia que proviene de otra fuente, qué harías con el usuario y la pregunta/respuesta?_.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave: Como esta pregunta ya tiene varios votos, prefiero no modificarla. Considera publicar la pregunta que propones como una respuesta. En el caso del propósito de este hilo creo que es la mejor forma de proceder ante una cambio "tan grande".

Comment: @Rubén Creo que quieres decir: `como esta _respuesta_` :) he publicado la respuesta. Gracias.

Answer (score -6):

¿Qué cosas te motivarían a seguir moderando?

Answer (score -10):

¿Quieres [Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/tour/documentation) en español? Y si lo quieres, ¿cómo intentarías implementarlo en SOes con lo que hay ahora mismo?