# ¿Cuanto tiempo es el mínimo que se requiere que dedique un moderador electo para que ejerza sus superpoderes?

Tags: soporte, elecciones, faq-de-moderadores

En [La recolección inicial de preguntas para la elección de los moderadores.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2390/65) estamos proponiendo preguntas a realizar a quienes se postulen para moderador de la comunidad.

Una de las preguntas propuestas trata sobre qué hacer en caso de que no le alcance el tiempo, lo cual me hace cuestionarme sobre el tiempo mínimo al que se compromete alguien que se postula y cómo se evalúa objetivamente si el moderador cumple con su compromiso en términos de tiempo.

Nótese que en [Una teoría de moderación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2227/65) se indica que un moderador de la comunidad debe hacer lo menos posible.

Comment: De esto se puede desprender la pregunta `Cuanto tiempo de tu dia piensas dedicarle a moderar en SOes`

Comment: Aunque Una teoría de moderación dice que los moderadores deben hacer lo menos posible en realidad hay que interpretarlo como que deben intervenir lo mínimo posible. Pueden y deben hacer mucho, pero interviniendo solo cuando es imprescindible. Como los cirujanos, han de buscar el mayor efecto con la mínima intervención.

Comment: Me parece una pregunta interesante, ya que de esto dependerá que haya gente que se presente o no, dependiendo del tiempo que dispongan

Answer (score 1):

Como es de esperarse esa respuesta depende de cada moderador.

En realidad no debería de haber un mínimo ya que cada uno ejerce sus funciones de acuerdo a sus posibilidades.

En mi caso en particular si soy elegido pienso dedicarle 1 hora diaria aproximadamente, 100% dedicado a revisar los reportes y a buscar cosas que mejorar con las herramientas de moderación y el resto del tiempo simplemente en el momento que este activo en el sitio.

Casi siempre que estoy frente a una PC tengo una pestaña de SOes abierta y cada cierto le doy un mirada a ver si aparecen preguntas que me interesen. De ser elegido moderador, durante este tiempo si bien no estaré activamente usando las herramientas de moderación si estaré listo por si aparecen reportes o hay alguna acción urgente de realizar.

Recuerden que se comenzará por elegir 3 moderadores, que cada uno tiene su rutina de trabajo y ocio y que cada uno dispone de más o menos tiempo que otros. Además con el tiempo irán creciendo en número por lo que la cantidad de horas dedicadas no debe ser un problema.