# Recolección inicial de preguntas para la elección de los moderadores 2019

Tags: discusión, elecciones

Nuestra comunidad está a punto de comenzar sus elecciones [la semana del 25 de marzo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/election/2). En conexión con eso, tendremos un tiempo de preguntas y respuestas con los candidatos. Esta será una oportunidad para que los miembros de la comunidad formulen preguntas para los candidatos sobre el tema de la moderación. La participación en cualquier parte de este proceso es completamente voluntaria.

Así es cómo esto funcionará:

- Permitiremos sugerencias de preguntas a los candidatos en este hilo hasta la fecha de inicio de la fase de nominaciones, que es el lunes 25 de marzo a las 10:00 UTC o 3:00 PM EST (dennos algunos momentos en lo que tardamos en entrar para cerrarlo - este proceso es manual). Publiquen respuestas aquí que contengan cualquier pregunta que ustedes quieran que los candidatos contesten. Por favor publiquen *una pregunta por cada respuesta*.
- Actuando en mi rol de gerente de esta comunidad, proporcionaré una selección corta de preguntas. Las primeras dos están garantizadas de estar en el cuestionario final y las demás se usarán solamente si no hay suficientes preguntas comunitarias.
- Si tu pregunta contiene un enlace, por favor usa el formato `[texto](enlace)`. Esto nos ayudará a poder copiar tu aportación fácilmente al cuestionario final.
- Este es el mejor momento de llamar la atención sobre cuestiones especificas y de preguntar sobre los asuntos que estamos viviendo en nuestra comunidad. ¿Cómo se enfrentarán los nuevos moderadores a estas situaciones? Pregúntenles.
- Al empezar nuestra fase de nominaciones, seleccionaré **hasta 8 de las preguntas más votadas por la comunidad** en este hilo y las usaré en combinación con las dos que yo entregaré. Reservo un poco de control editorial en la selección de preguntas y tengo también el derecho de no seleccionar cualquier pregunta (sin importar cuantos votos tenga) que no trate de (1) el tema de la moderación del sitio (2) la elección o (3) preguntas irrelevantes. Dicho esto, si tengo problema con alguna pregunta por no ser lo suficientemente clara, dejaré comentarios para que el autor pueda editar su aportación antes de la selección final de las preguntas.
- Estando seleccionadas las preguntas finales, una nueva pregunta se abrirá en el Meta para contener la lista para los candidatos.  Típicamente, esta lista tendrá 10 preguntas en total.
- Nótese que esta no es la única manera de obtener información sobre los candidatos.  Se vale, por ejemplo, el tener una sesión de chat con ellos para preguntar cosas adicionales o tal vez para aclarar lo que se ha presentado.

Si hay preguntas sobre este proceso, por favor comenten aquí.

---

El [cuestionario oficial está aquí](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4015/10). Ya no estamos aceptando preguntas nuevas.

Answer (score 15):

Me parece que nadie esta preguntando lo realmente importante:

¿Por qué querés ser moderador/a?

Answer (score 13):

Voy a citar [una pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2440/60415) que se hizo en las anteriores elecciones y que creo que vendría muy bien para aclarar [un caso](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3900/por-qu%C3%A9-un-moderador-borr%C3%B3-mi-comentario-en-el-que-preguntaba-por-una-edici%C3%B3n) que pasó hace poco con uno de los moderadores:

¿Qué harías si un usuario te acusa de abusar de tus privilegios como moderador?

Comment: Creo que esta es una muy buena pregunta que todos los aspirantes deberian contestar.

Answer (score 10):

De la [anterior elección](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2416/83) y con especial relevancia porque creo que este aspecto debería ser importantísimo para un moderador:

¿Cómo te sienta sentirte *escudriñado* constantemente en el chat y en Meta por las decisiones que tomes y tener que dar explicaciones sobre ellas?

Answer (score 9):

Aquí les dejo una lista general de preguntas favoritas recolectadas de diferentes elecciones de nuestra red. Como mencioné en las instrucciones anteriores, las primeras dos están garantizadas de aparecer en el cuestionario final. Si al terminar esta semana no tenemos por lo menos 8 preguntas comunitarias, usaré algunas más de esta lista para llenar los espacios.

Si les gusta una de las otras preguntas propuestas aquí, las pueden usar tal y como las ven o las pueden modificar si bien les parece. Recuerden que queremos ver **una pregunta por cada respuesta**.

---

**Mis preguntas a los candidatos:**

- ¿Cómo tratarías a un usuario que produce una corriente estable de respuestas valiosas pero que tiende a generar una cantidad grande de argumentos/reportes de los comentarios?
- ¿Cómo enfrentarías una situación en la que otro moderador cerró/eliminó/etc una pregunta que no crees que lo debía ser?

**Preguntas adicionales:**

- ¿En tú opinion, qué es lo que hacen los moderadores?
- Un diamante se pondrá en cada comentario, pregunta, y respuesta que hayas hecho en el pasado. Todo lo que has hecho se verá bajo una luz diferente.  ¿Cómo te hace sentir eso?
- ¿En qué forma piensas que el ser moderador te hará más efectivo al contrario que simplemente llegar a 10k o 20k puntos de reputación?

**Se espera una pregunta por cada respuesta. La única excepción es la primera respuesta (la mía) siendo que tengo que dar las 2 preguntas oficiales y otros ejemplos.**

Comment: Yo agregaria el moderador debe obtener un minimo de medallas que tengan un impacto mayor en la  comunidad.

Comment: @MiguelZarate eso ya es así. Véase [¿Con base en qué fundamentos puedo calificar o ser seleccionado como moderador?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1131/83)

Answer (score 8):

<sub>Recupero [una mía de la anterior elección](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2393/83), que no fue seleccionada pero tuvo bastante buena acogida.</sub>

Un moderador es un usuario normal al que se le dan una serie de herramientas adicionales. Por tanto, las tareas de edición, comentar, cerrar y abrir preguntas, etc es algo que sigue pudiendo hacer. Sin embargo, también puede contactar con los usuarios de forma privada, administrar etiquetas, juntar preguntas, interactuar con otros moderadores (del mismo sitio o de otros), perseguir a los empleados de Stack Exchange para conseguir nuevas funcionalidades para tu sitio...

Teniendo todo esto en cuenta, ¿en qué te gustaría  invertir la mayor parte de su tiempo como moderador y con qué finalidad? Esboza tu idea de qué podría definirse como éxito al realizar tal labor.

Answer (score 8):

Otra **[muy buena pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2392/60415)** de entre las que se hicieron las elecciones pasadas, y que me parece interesante la respuesta es:

*¿Qué criterios sigues para moderar preguntas de tecnologías de las que no tienes conocimientos?*

Comment: Esta pregunta la formulo @paperbirdmaster

Comment: la pregunta es duplicada

Answer (score 5):

Con frecuencia vemos respuestas de usuarios muy nuevos que son apenas un comentario. Muchas veces es útil, pero también es verdad que son apenas comentarios con buena intención y que muchas veces el usuario no vuelve para editarlos y mejorarlos.

Como moderador tendrías la opción de eliminar la respuesta o de convertirla en comentario. Mójate: ¿cuál sería tu criterio general en estas situaciones? ¿Crees que una serie de respuestas cortitas son beneficiosas para el sitio?

Answer (score 4):

Voy a recuperar una pregunta que ya hice en la anterior elección de moderadores:

¿Qué modo de acción te parece más adecuado para un moderador ♦? ¿Usar las herramientas de moderación solo en los casos indispensables que no pueda resolver la comunidad por sí misma o ser mucho más proactivo y tratar de actuar sobre el máximo de ámbitos del sitio para tratar que las preguntas y respuestas sean de la máxima calidad posible?

En resumen, ¿crees que el principal moderador de la comunidad debe ser ésta misma, o crees que la labor de moderación ♦ debe ser amplia para velar por la calidad de las publicaciones del sitio?

Answer (score 0):

Ya que, comparado con SO, desde hace poco tenemos moderadores electos, se me viene a la mente estas dos.

De los moderadores actuales, ¿Que cosas buenas has aprendido que quieres imitar y que cosas regulares quieres mejorar?

Answer (score 0):

A nivel de comunidad tengo una inquietud:

¿Cómo podemos (con tu ayuda) hacer crecer la comunidad de SOes de forma sana? Me gusta nuestra comunidad, y sueño con que sea más grande e importante ¿Qué puedes aportar a ese sueño?

Answer (score 0):

Al ser moderador,

¿De que forma que crees que tu participación en este "rol" podría mejorar o cambiar de manera positiva el sitio?

Comment: Pregunta interesante, pero creo que repite lo esencial que ya [ha planteado PaperBird](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3993/83)

Answer (score -2):

Voy al grano:

¿Tabuladores o espacios?

Comment: Esta pregunta es extremadamente importante. La gente civilizada usa espacios, los bárbaros tabuladores. No quiero un moderador que use tabuladores.