# 2019 Elección de Moderador - Cuestionario

Tags: discusión, elecciones

En relación con las [elecciones de moderadores](https://es.stackoverflow.com/election), tenemos este hilo de preguntas y respuestas para los candidatos. Las preguntas recolectadas [de este hilo anterior](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3978/10) han sido organizadas aquí.  Este espacio será el lugar en donde los candidatos darán sus respuestas.

He seleccionado las preguntas para la lista oficial y las comparto aquí también. Tenemos 10 preguntas en total, 2 mías y 8 de la comunidad seleccionadas por votos a favor.

**Para los candidatos:**

Vuestra tarea es simple - publicad una respuesta citando cada una de las preguntas y luego compartid vuestras respuestas a cada pregunta en esa misma respuesta. Para vuestra conveniencia, incluiré todas las preguntas en formato de cita con un espacio entre cada pregunta para que allí podáis insertar la respuesta. Solamente copiad la lista (al editar la pregunta) entera y poned vuestras respuestas entre las preguntas. Por favor considerad poner tu nombre al principio de la publicación para que los lectores sepan quiénes sois antes de terminar de leer todo lo que habéis escrito.  Por favor incluid también un enlace a vuestra entrada de postulación.

En cuanto todas las respuestas hayan sido compiladas, este servirá de transcripción para los electores para ver los pensamientos de sus candidatos.

¡Les deseamos suerte a los candidatos!

**Oh, y en cuanto hayáis terminado con las respuestas, por favor dejad un enlace al terminar este pedacito de texto, antes de las 3 rayitas (la regla horizontal). Por favor dejad los enlaces en la orden de presentación.**

Para ahorrarles tiempo, aquí están las respuestas de los candidatos (en orden de presentación):

[Respuestas de Gonzalo Bianchi (gbianchi)](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4017/324)

[Respuestas de Diego Avila](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4018/81846)

[Respuestas de Fredy Guibert (fredyfx)](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4019/822)

[Respuestas de Mario Guiber](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4020/)

[Respuestas de Andrés Salcedo (Alfabravo)](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4025/)

[Respuestas de Raul Cacacho](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4026/)

[Respuestas de Pikoh](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4032/)

[Respuestas de Blitz](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4033/7176/)

---

> 1. ¿Cómo tratarías a un usuario que produce una corriente estable de respuestas valiosas pero que tiende a generar una cantidad grande de argumentos/reportes de los comentarios?
> 2. ¿Cómo enfrentarías una situación en la que otro moderador cerró/eliminó/etc una pregunta que no crees que lo debía ser?
> 3. ¿Por qué quieres ser moderador/a?
> 4. Un moderador es un usuario normal al que se le dan una serie de herramientas adicionales. Por tanto, las tareas de edición, comentar, cerrar y abrir preguntas, etc es algo que sigue pudiendo hacer. Sin embargo, también puede contactar con los usuarios de forma privada, administrar etiquetas, juntar preguntas, interactuar con otros moderadores (del mismo sitio o de otros), perseguir a los empleados de Stack Exchange para conseguir nuevas funcionalidades para tu sitio...
>
>    Teniendo todo esto en cuenta, ¿en qué te gustaría invertir la mayor parte de su tiempo como moderador y con qué finalidad? Esboza tu idea de qué podría definirse como éxito al realizar tal labor.
> 5. ¿Qué modo de acción te parece más adecuado para un moderador ♦? ¿Usar las herramientas de moderación solo en los casos indispensables que no pueda resolver la comunidad por sí misma o ser mucho más pro-activo y tratar de actuar sobre el máximo de ámbitos del sitio para tratar que las preguntas y respuestas sean de la máxima calidad posible?
>
>    En resumen, ¿crees que el principal moderador de la comunidad debe ser ésta misma, o crees que la labor de moderación ♦ debe ser amplia para velar por la calidad de las publicaciones del sitio?
> 6. ¿Qué harías si un usuario te acusa de abusar de tus privilegios como moderador?
> 7. Si te llega un reporte y notas que se debe a una disputa entre dos o más usuarios, tomando en cuenta que los usuarios se insultan, amedrentan y se agreden mutuamente: ¿Cuál sería tu postura? ¿Qué acciones tomarías para mediar la disputa? ¿Cómo resolverías el conflicto?
> 8. ¿Cómo lidiarías antes los insultos o bien conversaciones que puedan tornarse turbulentas?

---

> 9. ¿Cómo te sienta sentirte escudriñado constantemente en el chat y en Meta por las decisiones que tomes y tener que dar explicaciones sobre ellas?
> 10. Cuando hay un problema en la comunidad que no está marcado (Al menos claramente) en las reglas del sitio ¿A quién le pides ayuda para saber como responder a la situación?

---

[Una sala de chat donde la comunidad puede hablar con los candidatos](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91537/2019-eleccion-de-moderador).

---

*Actualizar*: Me perdí dos preguntas, lo siento. Los he agregado al final de la lista (#9, #10).

Comment: @ManucoBianco Me perdí dos preguntas, lo siento. Los he agregado al final de la lista. (Traducido con la ayuda de Google Translate.)

Comment: Where do questions 7 and 8 come from? From 2017's elections?

Comment: @fedorqui Yes, it's correct.

Comment: es genial como StackOverflow Es va mejorando :D

Answer (score 51):

Mi nombre es Gonzalo Bianchi, y estas son mis respuestas al cuestionario propuesto.

El enlace a la postulación es el [siguiente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/election/2#post-248742)

> ¿Cómo tratarías a un usuario que produce una corriente estable de respuestas valiosas pero que tiende a generar una cantidad grande de argumentos/reportes de los comentarios?

Sigo pensando igual que la última vez. Hay que ver qué clase de reportes genera, y porque genera los mismos. Lo mejor es hablar con él, y ver porque piensa que esos reportes son correctos. Muchas veces los puntos de vista se pueden resolver hablando más que generando una serie de comentarios. Como Moderador, esa es una ventaja.

> ¿Cómo enfrentarías una situación en la que otro moderador cerró/eliminó/etc una pregunta que no crees que lo debía ser?

Hablando. Los moderadores pueden hablar entre si. La ventaja de que seamos pocos es que ya casi podemos ponernos de acuerdo con solo mirarnos. Con la mayoría (creo que con todos, pero no quiero generalizar porque es mi punto de vista) de los moderadores actuales tengo una relación muy fluida, al punto que muchas veces termino pidiéndoles yo el cierre o poniéndonos de acuerdo por afuera (muchas veces en el chat). Pero si, si considero que alguien cerro mal algo, una charla amena puede solucionar el problema sin mas.

> ¿Por qué quieres ser moderador/a?

Porque creo que eliminaría un poco los idas y vueltas para enseñarle a usuarios nuevos a usar el sitio. Porque me he enfocado últimamente en la resolución de problemas en el mismo, y no tengo conflictos con nadie. Porque me gusta la resolución de conflictos y vengo trabajando los últimos 2 años constantemente en el sitio. Quiero ser moderador porque me gusta el sitio, me gusta lo que hacemos con el, y me siento parte del mismo.

> Un moderador es un usuario normal al que se le dan una serie de herramientas adicionales. Por tanto, las tareas de edición, comentar, cerrar y abrir preguntas, etc es algo que sigue pudiendo hacer. Sin embargo, también puede contactar con los usuarios de forma privada, administrar etiquetas, juntar preguntas, interactuar con otros moderadores (del mismo sitio o de otros), perseguir a los empleados de Stack Exchange para conseguir nuevas funcionalidades para tu sitio...
>   Teniendo todo esto en cuenta, ¿en qué te gustaría invertir la mayor parte de su tiempo como moderador y con qué finalidad? Esboza tu idea de qué podría definirse como éxito al realizar tal labor.

Muchas de esas tareas ya las vengo realizando. Persigo a nicolas como CM para hacer algunas cosas. Con el conseguimos poner los banner de ayuda a los usuarios. Me gustaría orientar sobre todo a los nuevos usuarios que están entrando en el sitio y dan sus primeros pasos para que puedan usar el sitio como corresponde. Me sentiría realizado si por mes pudiéramos generar uno o dos nuevos usuarios que sepan manejar medianamente bien el sitio.

> ¿Qué modo de acción te parece más adecuado para un moderador ♦? ¿Usar las herramientas de moderación solo en los casos indispensables que no pueda resolver la comunidad por sí misma o ser mucho más proactivo y tratar de actuar sobre el máximo de ámbitos del sitio para tratar que las preguntas y respuestas sean de la máxima calidad posible?
>   En resumen, ¿crees que el principal moderador de la comunidad debe ser ésta misma, o crees que la labor de moderación ♦ debe ser amplia para velar por la calidad de las publicaciones del sitio?

Creo que la moderación de preguntas y respuesta sigue estando en la comunidad. Opino igual que Alvaro en ese sentido, es difícil tener un superpoder y usarlo a discreción. Siempre opte por decirle al usuario que hace falta para que sus preguntas sean mucho mejores. Mientras no sea una pregunta flagrantemente fuera de contexto, me gustaría que se fuera resolviendo naturalmente. Y si, estar siempre presente para evitar que algunas cosas pasen de largo sin que nadie las frene.

> ¿Que harias si un usuario te acusa de abusar de tus privilegios como moderador?

Pondria a disposición todas las herramientas que tengo a mano para mostrar lo que hice, y en caso de haber cometido un error me disculparía como se debe. Creo que todos podemos equivocarnos, y el sitio es un lugar con aciertos y errores a cada rato. La sola idea de pensar que puedo abusar, hasta sin darme cuenta de mis errores, es algo que esta siempre presente. El sitio no es mio, es de todos. Yo solo tengo un poder que me otorgaron entre todos para ayudarlos a llevar el sitio adelante (en caso de ser electo).

> Si te llega un reporte y notas que se debe a una disputa entre dos o más usuarios, tomando en cuenta que los usuarios se insultan, amedrentan y se agreden mutuamente: ¿Cuál sería tu postura? ¿Qué acciones tomarías para mediar la disputa? ¿Cómo resolverías el conflicto?

Primero, como si fueran niños, separarlos. Borrar todo contacto entre los mismos, hasta tanto pueda hablar con los dos y ver que causo todo el lio. Este lugar tiene que ser amplio, y hay otras personas que no tienen porque tolerar una riña en vivo y directo. Hay un lindo código de conducta, y eso incluye ser tolerantes con quien piensa diferente. No todos venimos del mismo lugar y no todos pensamos igual, pero hay que abtraerse de esas cosas, y mediar.

> ¿Cómo lidiarías antes los insultos o bien conversaciones que puedan tornarse turbulentas?

Lo mismo que la de anterior pregunta, Si se trata de insultos eliminaría los comentarios y hablaría con los involucrados por separado. Si es una conversación que se esta tornando turbulenta, tal vez un comentario a tiempo bajaría los decibeles. A veces solo hace falta tiempo y abrirse para ver la perspectiva. Siempre hay que tener en cuenta, que puede que una técnica que puede funcionar en un caso, no funcione en otro. A mi me gustaría que siempre fuera la misma forma de solucionar, pero no necesariamente funciona en todos los casos.

> ¿Cómo te sienta sentirte escudriñado constantemente en el chat y en Meta por las decisiones que tomes y tener que dar explicaciones sobre ellas?

No tengo ningún problema con que mis acciones sean analizadas todos los días por toda la comunidad. Sin darnos cuenta, eso pasa cada vez que dejamos un comentario, una pregunta o una respuesta. Es algo con lo que convivimos. Con un diamante, tal vez todavía se hile más fino, pero es algo que aprendí a manejar y un reto que con gusto tomare.

> Cuando hay un problema en la comunidad que no está marcado (Al menos claramente) en las reglas del sitio ¿A quién le pides ayuda para saber como responder a la situación?

Puede que surjan cosas nuevas, y seguro siempre surge alguna. Como primera medida, esto depende de qué tipo de hecho ocurra. Hay cosas que se pueden discutir en meta, y llegar a un acuerdo entre todos. Esto debería ser siempre el primer pasó. Si la cuestión que surge es un poco más complicada que algo del sitio, están los otros moderadores, y sobre todo los moderadores con muchísima más experiencia en sitios más viejos, a los cuales se les puede consultar para tener una posición antes de exponer el problema a la comunidad, si es que corresponde.

---

En caso de faltar preguntas, con gusto las contesto en comentarios.

Otra nota: voy a estar de vacaciones durante parte de las primarias y los primeros dias de la eleccion general. Sin embargo podre contestar preguntas, pero no con la velocidad que se esperaria.

Comment: Nadie mejor para ocupar esa posición que vos ;)

Comment: Siempre constante ayudando en las tareas de moderación, mucha suerte maestro Bianchi.

Comment: Sin duda te mereces ser moderador, suerte compañero.

Comment: No llevo mucho participando en SO pero sí que te reconozco como alguien activo y que colabora diariamente. Mucha suerte!

Comment: Creo que sos la persona indicada para esta posición.. cada vez que tuve una duda sobre el funcionamiento del sitio, si una pregunta debía o no ser respondida, si una respuesta era de mala calidad, siempre estabas en el chat con la mejor para ayudarme a resolver la situación de la mejor manera! ¡Muchos Éxitos!

Comment: ¡Genial que te presentes! Pregunta: actualmente eres activo en las colas, participas en los proyectos relacionados (traducir.win) y en el chat (tanto en el del sitio como The Terminal). ¿En qué punto consideras que ser moderador te ayudará a mejorar la comunidad? Es decir, ¿qué no puedes hacer ahora que te gustaría poder hacer?

Comment: @fedorqui Creo que el sitio es mas que lo que vemos los usuarios con "poderes" de mods. Creo que hay todo un transfondo de usuarios duplicados, usuarios con problemas y cosas que no vemos los usuarios comunes, en las que seria tambien muy bueno ayudar. Siento que he entrenado un monton de nuevos usuarios que pueden ir filtrando las publicaciones, y yo ayudar desde el transfondo con los otros problemas que nos vemos, esos que loisb dice que tardan un monton en solucionar.

Comment: ¿Conociendo algunos de los retos que se tiene día a día como moderador, cual o cuales serían las primeras cosas en que actuarías para mejora del sitio?

Comment: @iuninefrendor antes de dedicarnos a eso, lo principal es cubrir las primeras necesidades que tengan los moderadores actuales. Tengamos en cuenta de que una eleccion es fruto de un crecimiento del sitio, y por lo tanto debe haber cosas de las que no estamos con tanto conocimiento. Si tuviera que hablar de algo puntual, SO va a implementar un wizard para ayudar a los usuarios novatos. Trabajar sobre ese sistema seria una de las primeras cosas que me gustaria hacer. Tanto sea en su traduccion, como en su implementación, siempre que sea posible (sabemos que dependemos de algo mas que nosotros)

Comment: En general sueles ser bastante estricto a la hora de cerrar preguntas y así has ido expresándolo en los debates al respecto en Meta. Con estricto me refiero a que tienes muy presente el _on-topic_. ¿Hay algún campo que creas que habría que modificar o ensanchar para permitir o dejar de permitir tipos de preguntas? Sé que no es estrictamente tarea de un moderador, pero sí suele ser interesante que ellos lo tengan presente para intentar orientar a la comunidad en un sentido u otro, abriendo debate, etc.

Comment: @fedorqui hay cosas que se van abriendo naturalmente. Soy estricto, porque me gusta que esto no se desborde. Pero hay un desborde natural. Las preguntas sobre base de datos bien armadas empezaron a fluir. Creo que ahi podria haber un nicho a trabajar, pero me gustaria verlo fluir por si mismo, mas que empujarlo.

Answer (score 25):

¡Hola buenas madrugadas! Vengo a postular :D

> ¿Cómo tratarías a un usuario que produce una corriente estable de respuestas valiosas pero que tiende a generar una cantidad grande de argumentos/reportes de los comentarios?

Con paciencia, muchos usuarios desconocen que debates extensos pueden migrarse a una sala de chat de la pregunta en sí. Conversar con el usuario para darle a entender que esta posibilidad existe, de paso que se mantiene un buen orden.

> ¿Cómo enfrentarías una situación en la que otro moderador cerró/eliminó/etc una pregunta que no crees que lo debía ser?

Conversando amablemente con el otro mod, todos tenemos puntos de vista diferentes, entender su punto de vista y encontrar un equilibrio es fundamental.

> ¿Por qué quieres ser moderador/a?

Por 3 motivos fundamentales: 1. Porque es una forma de agradecer a toda la gente que comparte en internet su conocimiento de manera libre. 2. Porque ahorraría tiempo en aquellas revisiones que piden votaciones para ser mejoradas. 3. Porque se siente tan bien contribuir al sitio de mejor manera con las herramientas que hay.

> Un moderador es un usuario normal al que se le dan una serie de herramientas adicionales. Por tanto, las tareas de edición, comentar, cerrar y abrir preguntas, etc es algo que sigue pudiendo hacer. Sin embargo, también puede contactar con los usuarios de forma privada, administrar etiquetas, juntar preguntas, interactuar con otros moderadores (del mismo sitio o de otros), perseguir a los empleados de Stack Exchange para conseguir nuevas funcionalidades para tu sitio... Teniendo todo esto en cuenta, ¿en qué te gustaría invertir la mayor parte de su tiempo como moderador y con qué finalidad? Esboza tu idea de qué podría definirse como éxito al realizar tal labor.

Me gustaría ordenar el sitio (algo que vengo haciendo desde hace mucho tiempo), hay preguntas que tienen títulos que explican todo el problema y cuerpos del mensaje que sólo son imágenes. Poder enviar un mensaje privado a los usuarios para que acepten la respuesta a su pregunta que hicieron hace 1 año para mantener la buena salud del sitio y poder guiarlos a que utilicen SOes de una buena manera. Tengo ideas sobre funcionalidades que me gustaría verlas implementadas en SOes como la parte de Jobs usando un mapa, entre otras.

> ¿Qué modo de acción te parece más adecuado para un moderador ♦? ¿Usar las herramientas de moderación solo en los casos indispensables que no pueda resolver la comunidad por sí misma o ser mucho más proactivo y tratar de actuar sobre el máximo de ámbitos del sitio para tratar que las preguntas y respuestas sean de la máxima calidad posible? En resumen, ¿crees que el principal moderador de la comunidad debe ser ésta misma, o crees que la labor de moderación ♦ debe ser amplia para velar por la calidad de las publicaciones del sitio?

La comunidad en sí es la principal moderación, hay preguntas y respuestas que bajo mi criterio puede ser malas y merecen ser cerradas sin embargo hay votaciones positivas tanto para la pregunta como para las respuestas y ello debe respetarse, mi labor en casos como éstos sería pulir la pregunta y respuestas con formatos adecuados.

> ¿Que harías si un usuario te acusa de abusar de tus privilegios como moderador?

Pediría disculpas en primer lugar y acto seguido solicitar que me explique cómo es que ha sentido ese abuso de mi parte. Somos humanos, podemos equivocarnos, enmendarnos y realizar un upgrade para seguir conviviendo en paz y armonía.

> Si te llega un reporte y notas que se debe a una disputa entre dos o más usuarios, tomando en cuenta que los usuarios se insultan, amedrentan y se agreguen mutuamente: ¿Cuál sería tu postura? ¿Qué acciones tomarías para mediar la disputa? ¿Cómo resolverías el conflicto?

Mi postura en este tipo de casos siempre es neutral, entender ambos puntos de vista, a veces uno tiene un día crítico y una sola gota derrama el vaso... o la jarra. Conversar con ambos usuarios por separado me da la chance de analizar lo que piensan y sienten, de esta manera utilizando palabras adecuadas para cada uno va a permitirme encontrar el balance y seguir de manera pacífica. No siempre lo que se escribe se lee en el mismo tono de voz con el que se piensa.

> ¿Cómo lidiarías antes los insultos o bien conversaciones que puedan tornarse turbulentas?

Similar al punto anterior, conversar con ambos usuarios por separado, a veces el problema más grande el ser humano es asumir alguna respuesta (errónea) antes de formular una pregunta con la que se puede tener una respuesta más cercana a la realidad.

> ¿Cómo te sienta sentirte escudriñado constantemente en el chat y en Meta por las decisiones que tomes y tener que dar explicaciones sobre ellas?

Totalmente bien, la transparencia es algo que siempre debe estar presente al igual que el equilibrio y la armonía entre la comunidad y la forma de moderación :D

> Cuando hay un problema en la comunidad que no está marcado (Al menos claramente) en las reglas del sitio ¿A quién le pides ayuda para saber como responder a la situación?

Para empezar, a los demás moderadores y luego compartir el punto de vista en META, teniendo como resultado la interacción con los pensamientos de la comunidad y en base a ello, determinar una metodología para afrontar este nuevo tipo de situaciones.

---

Muchas gracias por su atención, les dejo el link oficial de mi candidatura a mod: https://es.stackoverflow.com/election/2#post-248739 aquí @fredyfx elevando el cosmos con todo el power 2.0!!!

Comment: Suerte compatriota. Creo que serías un gran moderador.

Comment: Señalas en una de tus respuestas: *Poder enviar un mensaje privado a los usuarios para que acepten la respuesta a su pregunta que hicieron hace 1 año*, ¿Qué pasa si ninguna de las respuestas le ayudo al OP? ¿No crees que generarías un efecto similar al *efecto meta*?

Comment: Muy buena pregunta, esa es una posibilidad y el resultado no se sabrá hasta que se intente, mientras tanto he comentado en un buen número de preguntas sobre si alguna respuesta le fue de utilidad, varias respuestas fueron aceptadas :D

Comment: @fredyfx por favor usa `@eyllanesc` para que me sea notificado tu respuesta, por otro lado no tiene el mismo peso el comentario de un moderador diamantado que un usuario que no lo es. Como señale en otro comentario: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4015/2019-elecci%c3%b3n-de-moderador-cuestionario?cb=1#comment15546_4022 en mi humilde opinión que en vez de actuar directamente(que tiene el riesgo de generar un ruido adicional) es mejor atraer más tráfico de vistas ya que el voto del OP nunca es decisivo, solo señala que le sirvio pero no implica que es la mejor respuesta-

Comment: Está bien, usaré el arroba. @eyllanesc creo que no me dejé entender, enviar un mensaje privado es diferente a dejar un comentario de la manera en que lo conocemos.

Comment: Mi idea no es cambiar tu postura, solo es que analices las posibles consecuencias. El mensaje privado minimiza el efecto pero creo que no es necesario ya que si muchas aceptaran la respuesta que obtenga solo por lo que lo señalo un moderador diamantado en vez de ser un voto espontaneo que es lo que se espera en SO. Es similar a los votos que ciertos usuarios dan a los post de un mismo usuario porque los ayudo antes sin saber si la respuesta es buena o no. :-), adios.

Comment: @eyllanesc Estamos en un escenario donde: 1. Respuesta que tuvo un "gracias sí me ayudó" y que no se marcó como aceptada. 2. Respuestas que no solucionan el problema. Lo del mensaje privado apunto al primer grupo, para el segundo grupo pregunto si alguna respuesta fue de utilidad o si se logró solucionar y en caso obtener feedback, comentar si puede compartir la respuesta, así todo el sitio sigue con buena salud por efecto de % de respuestas resueltas y más usuarios que tengan la misma situación o algo similar puedan tener ideas para completar la feature de su desarrollo :D

Comment: En caso que sea elegido moderador (en lo cual no estoy de acuerdo pero lo veo muy probable), sugeriría no utilizar expresiones como: _elevando el cosmos con todo el power 2.0!!!_

Comment: ¿Conociendo algunos de los retos que se tiene día a día como moderador, cual o cuales serían las primeras cosas en que actuarías para mejora del sitio?

Comment: @Shaz vale, entendido :D #iuninefrendor lo primero que haría sería apoyar con la cola de revisión para tratar de reducirla al máximo posible, aquí es donde se ven preguntas de baja calidad, ediciones y detalles para dejar abierta o cerrar preguntas, tiene un máximo de 20 revisiones para usuarios normales, sin embargo para moderadores la situación cambia

Comment: !Ups, acabo de ver te has postulado hermano¡, ya tienes experiencia en moderación del sitio. ¡Con todo el poder maestro Fredyfx \m/!

Comment: Muchas gracias maestro Jorgesys :D veamos qué decide la comunidad

Answer (score 21):

> 1. ¿Cómo tratarías a un usuario que produce una corriente estable de respuestas valiosas pero que tiende a generar una cantidad grande de argumentos/reportes de los comentarios?

En primer lugar, trataría de hacerle ver la situación que está provocando e intentaría que recapacite sobre su actitud, privadamente al principio, y haciendo uso de Meta si fuera necesario para aclarar alguna situación particular.

Pero si finalmente los reportes que se le levanten son consistentes, adecuados y justificados, aplicaría las sanciones necesarias acorde a la gravedad de los mismos (eliminación de comentarios ofensivos, bans temporales, y en casos extremadamente graves, eliminación del usuario).

> 2. ¿Cómo enfrentarías una situación en la que otro moderador cerró/eliminó/etc una pregunta que no crees que lo debía ser?

Hay vías de comunicación con otros moderadores, así que lo primero sería por supuesto conversar con él para entender cuales fueron sus motivos, y , o bien aceptar su decisión si éstos me convencieran, o dado el caso tratar de convencerle de su equivocación.

En caso de no llegar a un acuerdo, lo sometería a la opinión del resto de moderadores, y en este caso que la mayoría decidiera.

> 3. ¿Por qué quieres ser moderador/a?

Esta pregunta es la que más me cuesta responder. En mi caso creo lo que mejor lo describe es una cita de John F. Kennedy: *No preguntes lo que tu país puede hacer por ti; pregunta lo que tú puedes hacer por tu país.*

La cuestión es que creo que es necesario un moderador en la franja horaria de España para ayudar a @lois6b. Dado que mis candidatos favoritos no quieren postularse, a pesar de no tener intención a priori de presentarme ya que considero la labor de moderador muy importante y que necesita una dedicación de tiempo importante, creo que por responsabilidad y por cariño al sitio debo al menos intentarlo.

Llevo bastante tiempo en Stack Overflow en Español, y desde que llegué he tratado de ayudar en la medida de mis posibilidades. Participando en Meta, en las colas de revisión, en cualquier proyecto paralelo que ha surgido al sitio...en realidad, creo que no cambiaría mucho el tiempo que dedico al sitio si fuera elegido.

> 4. Un moderador es un usuario normal al que se le dan una serie de herramientas adicionales. Por tanto, las tareas de edición, comentar, cerrar y abrir preguntas, etc es algo que sigue pudiendo hacer. Sin embargo, también puede contactar con los usuarios de forma privada, administrar etiquetas, juntar preguntas, interactuar con otros moderadores (del mismo sitio o de otros), perseguir a los empleados de Stack Exchange para conseguir nuevas funcionalidades para tu sitio...
>
>    Teniendo todo esto en cuenta, ¿en qué te gustaría invertir la mayor parte de su tiempo como moderador y con qué finalidad? Esboza tu idea de qué podría definirse como éxito al realizar tal labor.

Yo tengo una opinión bastante clara de cual debe ser la labor de un moderador diamantado en el sitio. Destacaría la resolución de conflictos (reportes principalmente), limpieza del sitio, contribuir en Meta todo lo posible, e interactuar con moderadores de otros sitios en beneficio de este.

En mi caso, siempre he pensado que al pasar a ser moderador diamantado, las colas de revisión pasarían a un segundo plano, ya que esa labor corresponde principalmente al resto de usuarios con la suficiente reputación para atenderlas. El hecho por ejemplo de que únicamente mi voto sea suficiente para cerrar una pregunta me haría usarlo en casos extremadamente claros, o en una labor de limpieza (publicaciones con varios votos de cierre que por la falta de usuarios con suficiente reputación no llegan a ser cerradas nunca y quedan abandonadas por ejemplo.

> 5. ¿Qué modo de acción te parece más adecuado para un moderador ♦? ¿Usar las herramientas de moderación solo en los casos indispensables que no pueda resolver la comunidad por sí misma o ser mucho más pro-activo y tratar de actuar sobre el máximo de ámbitos del sitio para tratar que las preguntas y respuestas sean de la máxima calidad posible?
>
>    En resumen, ¿crees que el principal moderador de la comunidad debe ser ésta misma, o crees que la labor de moderación ♦ debe ser amplia para velar por la calidad de las publicaciones del sitio?

Esta pregunta creo que la he respondido con la anterior. Pero por concretar, si, yo opino que es la comunidad la que debe autoregularse y autogestionarse en todo lo posible mediante los privilegios que todos los usuarios pueden ganar a medida que suben en reputación.

Otra cuestión diferente es tratar de ayudar a que la calidad de las publicaciones sea la máxima posible. Pero eso se puede lograr ayudando a los nuevos (y a veces viejos) usuarios con comentarios indicando las normas del sitio, o sugiriendo modificaciones que pueden ser deseables. Así he actuado desde que estoy en el sitio, y eso no cambiaría aunque lograra ser elegido como moderador.

> 6. ¿Qué harías si un usuario te acusa de abusar de tus privilegios como moderador?

Espero que nunca llegara el caso, pero si ocurriera primero trataría de conversar con el, exponer las razones de mi actuación apoyándome en las normas del sitio, y lo comentaría con los otros moderadores para tratar de recabar opiniones y dilucidar si efectivamente me he equivocado. Si así fuera, no tendría problema en pedir disculpas y modificar mi actuación. En caso contrario, explicaría al usuario las opciones que tiene si siguiera estando en desacuerdo (principalmente, consultar en Meta o ponerse directamente en contacto con el equipo de StackExchange).

> 7. Si te llega un reporte y notas que se debe a una disputa entre dos o más usuarios, tomando en cuenta que los usuarios se insultan, amedrentan y se agreden mutuamente: ¿Cuál sería tu postura? ¿Qué acciones tomarías para mediar la disputa? ¿Cómo resolverías el conflicto?

Ante todo, antes de actuar recabaría toda la información para tratar de averiguar cual es problema. Eliminaría lo antes posible todo comentario susceptible de ser ofensivo hacia otros. Llamaría a todos los implicados al orden, recordando las normas de conducta del sitio y trataría de apaciguar la situación amistosamente. Si, finalmente, los insultos o agresiones continuaran, sancionaría a los implicados de acuerdo a la gravedad de la situación.

> 8. ¿Cómo lidiarías antes los insultos o bien conversaciones que puedan tornarse turbulentas?

Creo que debo remitirme a mi anterior respuesta, alli he explicado cual sería mi forma de actuar.

---

> 9. ¿Cómo te sienta sentirte escudriñado constantemente en el chat y en Meta por las decisiones que tomes y tener que dar explicaciones sobre ellas?

Yo considero que una conciencia tranquila hace que cualquier situación de ese tipo que se de no tenga ninguna importancia. Ser moderador conlleva una responsabilidad muy alta, y que haya usuarios que puedan enfadarse contigo o exigir explicaciones sobre una determinada acción va con el cargo. Resumiendo, es algo que entiendo y asumo.

> 10. Cuando hay un problema en la comunidad que no está marcado (Al menos claramente) en las reglas del sitio ¿A quién le pides ayuda para saber como responder a la situación?

Creo que el proceso está bastante definido: a otros moderadores, y a la comunidad (mediante una publicación en Meta). Las normas del sitio nos las damos todos los usuarios, y Meta es el lugar indicado para decidir sobre cualquier cuestión del sitio que no haya quedado definida previamente.

---

[Postulación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/election/2#post-249537)

Comment: Pregunta que se me ocurre: actualmente eres de los poquitos que entra con frecuencia en las colas de revisión. Comentas que reducirías tu tiempo allí, cosa que me parece totalmente razonable. ¿Qué crees que podrías hacer como moderador para intentar conseguir más implicación en las colas? Además de la pregunta típica: ¿qué quieres hacer que ahora mismo no puedas como usuario _no_ diamantado? Es decir, ¿puedes expandir un poco lo de "limpieza del sitio"?

Comment: @fedorqui en realidad ya hace un tiempo que he reducido mi tiempo en las colas, ya que quería ver como iban sin la aportación continúa que yo estaba realizando. Pero en este caso me refería principalmente a la cola de cierre, ya que opino que salvo en casos excepcionales, las preguntas deben ser cerradas por los usuarios con reputación suficiente para ello, y no por un mod diamantado ya que elimina el "consenso" al generar un cierre inmediato.

Comment: @fedorqui en cuanto a la "limpieza" del sitio, como explico aqui, hay muchas publicaciones que se quedan con 3/4 votos de cierre (creo que tenemos una falta grande de usuarios con reputación alta) y "ensucian" el sitio. En esos casos si que creo que la labor como mod es cerrar(y en su caso eliminar) publicaciones que han quedado "colgadas" y faltas de atención, sin respuestas y sin aportar nada al sitio.

Comment: @fedorqui  en cuanto a que podría hacer para conseguir más implicación en las colas, creo que es algo muy dificil siendo o no moderador. Yo veo básico promocionar que la gente vote mas, mucho mas. Aumentar la base de usuarios con reputación suficiente para moderar es básico en el sitio ahora mismo. Pero creo que esto no es algo que sea labor de moderador, sino de todos los usuarios. Yo por mi parte suelo dejar comentarios explicando sobre todo a usuarios nuevos que deben aceptar y votar si las respuestas les han ayudado. Tal vez con un diamante al lado me hagan mas caso :)

Comment: Mmm yo creo que sí que hay margen por parte de un moderador: se pueden poner unas publicaciones en [meta-tag:destacado] (en Spanish.SE nos funcionó bastante bien para aumentar votos, por ejemplo), se puede ser más estricto con los comentarios y arrastrar a la gente a contestar y no comentar. Totalmente de acuerdo en que hace falta aumentar la base de gente con capacidad de moderar.

Comment: Si resultara elegido, me permitirás que tome prestadas tu idea sobre las publicaciones destacadas @fedorqui. En cuanto al tema de los comentarios, es complicado. Cualquiera puede aconsejar a otro usuario que convierta su comentario en respuesta. Si te refieres a eliminar comentarios, creo que para eso hay que tener mas cuidado.

Comment: No tiene copyright, todo tuyo : ) Yo la idea de eliminar comentarios que responden la cogí del CM Robert Cartaino, que suele ser bastante incisivo en eso. No sé si en SOes es un problema grande, pero puede ser interesante.

Answer (score 4):

Saludos a todos estas son mis respuestas

```
1. ¿Cómo tratarías a un usuario que produce una corriente estable de respuestas
valiosas pero que tiende a generar una cantidad grande de argumentos/reportes de 
los comentarios?
```

Lo primero que haría invitarlo a usar las salas de chat para evitar tener tantos comentarios en las respuestas, si tuviera alguna duda ayudarle a resolverlas.

```
2. ¿Cómo enfrentarías una situación en la que otro moderador cerró/eliminó/etc 
una pregunta que no crees que lo debía ser?
```

Pues poder expresar mi punto de vista y poder llegar un consenso para que se tome la mejor decisión para el sitio.

```
3. ¿Por qué quieres ser moderador/a?
```

Porque quiero seguir ayudando a la comunidad, apoyando con los problemas ya que tengo bastante tiempo apoyando en las listas de revisiones.

```
4. Un moderador es un usuario normal al que se le dan una serie de herramientas
adicionales. Por tanto, las tareas de edición, comentar, cerrar y abrir preguntas, 
etc es algo que sigue pudiendo hacer. Sin embargo, también puede contactar 
con los usuarios de forma privada, administrar etiquetas, juntar preguntas, 
interactuar con otros moderadores (del mismo sitio o de otros), perseguir a 
los empleados de Stack Exchange para conseguir nuevas funcionalidades para tu sitio...
```

Algunas de estas funciones no las hecho pero, creo que con amabilidad y cortesía para solicitar las cosas, se pueden lograr que avances los proyectos de mejora para sitio. Por otra parte hablar con los usuarios seria de manera educada no ofendiendo a nadie se lograría una buena comunicación.

```
5. Teniendo todo esto en cuenta, ¿en qué te gustaría invertir la mayor parte de su tiempo 
como moderador y con qué finalidad? Esboza tu idea de qué podría definirse como   
éxito al realizar tal labor.
```

Seguir trabajando en las colas de revisión, en pensar como podría mejorar el sitio, ayudar a resolver problemas y trabajar para que crezca más el sitio

```
6. ¿Qué modo de acción te parece más adecuado para un moderador ♦? ¿Usar las herramientas 
de moderación solo en los casos indispensables que no pueda resolver la comunidad por sí misma 
o ser mucho más pro-activo y tratar de actuar sobre el máximo de ámbitos  del sitio 
 para tratar que las preguntas y respuestas sean de la máxima calidad posible?
```

Los usuarios ayudamos bastante en la moderación del sitio, dejaría que los usuarios sigan trabajando, siempre buscando que las preguntas sean de calidad y cumpla con los estándares que requiere el sitio.

```
7. En resumen, ¿crees que el principal moderador de la comunidad debe ser
ésta misma, o crees que la labor de moderación ♦ debe ser amplia para velar 
por la calidad de las publicaciones del sitio?
```

Somos una comunidad y todos velamos por la calidad de las publicaciones y con esta ayuda se puede velar por otros proyectos para mejorar el sitio, siempre contestando preguntas y ayudando en las colas de moderación.

```
8. ¿Qué harías si un usuario te acusa de abusar de tus privilegios como moderador?
```

Pues podríamos hablar, ver el punto de vista del usuario porque piensa eso, un buen lugar podría ser el chat para dejar evidencia de lo que hablamos y la conclusión que llegamos.

```
9. Si te llega un reporte y notas que se debe a una disputa entre dos o más usuarios, tomando 
en cuenta que los usuarios se insultan, amedrentan y se agreden mutuamente: 
¿Cuál sería tu postura? ¿Qué acciones tomarías para mediar la disputa? 
¿Cómo resolverías el conflicto?
```

Conocer ambas partes, eliminar comentarios ofensivos, tratar de llegar a un acuerdo como profesionales sin ofender a ninguna parte haciendo mi mayor esfuerzo por que las partes queden satisfechas.

```
10. ¿Cómo lidiarías antes los insultos o bien conversaciones que puedan tornarse turbulentas?
```

Calmarme y recordar que en ese momento ya soy un moderador ♦, que soy ejemplo para otros usuario y debo de comportarme como tal.

```
11. ¿Cómo te sienta sentirte escudriñado constantemente en el chat y en 
Meta por las decisiones que tomes y tener que dar explicaciones sobre ellas?
```

Recordar que las decisiones que se tomen deben de ser para que el sitio mejore, no porque sea influenciado por otra situación que no sea trasparente, no tendría ningún problema que me escudriñen en el chat.

```
12. Cuando hay un problema en la comunidad que no está marcado (Al menos claramente) 
en las reglas del sitio ¿A quién le pides ayuda para saber como responder a la situación?
```

Hay mas moderadores con mas tiempo podría consultar a ellos si ellos no supieran por alguna razón, el chat de nuestra comunidad es una herramienta excelente ya que hay muchos con mucho conocimiento que podrían ayudarme con la duda que tendría para poder tomar la decisión

Muchas gracias dejo mi link de [Postulación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/election/2#post-248738)

Comment: ¡Buenas respuestas, Raul! No entiendo que no tengas más puntuación en esta respuesta. ¿Qué cosas que no puedes hacer ahora querrías hacer como moderador? Es decir, ¿qué herramientas echas en falta en tu día a día que pasarías a tener si eres elegido moderador?

Comment: @fedorqui gracias, aprender mas sobre los reportes, las otras listas de revisión y me gustaría poder pedir mejoras al sitio por ejemplo el logo del sitio me gustaría que fuera diferente y no tan parecido al sito en ingles

Answer (score 2):

Saludos me presente soy Diego Avila y estas son mis respuestas:

> ¿Cómo tratarías a un usuario que produce una corriente estable de respuestas valiosas pero que tiende a generar una cantidad grande de argumentos/reportes de los comentarios?

Sin dudar la mejor opción es el dialogo y analizar los puntos de vista del porque de la gran cantidad de reportes y poder llegar a un entendimiento y mantener una adecuada convivencia en la comunidad.

> ¿Cómo enfrentarías una situación en la que otro moderador cerró/eliminó/etc una pregunta que no crees que lo debía ser?

Dialogar con el moderador y ver su punto de vista el porque su accionar y tomar la mejor decisión por el bienestar de la comunidad.

> ¿Por qué quieres ser moderador/a?

Deseo ser Moderador para aportar mi granito de arena a que esta comunidad crezca como lo ha venido haciendo, respetando y haciendo respetar las normas/reglas de convivencia manteniendo el respeto, amabilidad y flexibilidad cuando lo amerite.

> Un moderador es un usuario normal al que se le dan una serie de herramientas adicionales. Por tanto, las tareas de edición, comentar, cerrar y abrir preguntas, etc es algo que sigue pudiendo hacer. Sin embargo, también puede contactar con los usuarios de forma privada, administrar etiquetas, juntar preguntas, interactuar con otros moderadores (del mismo sitio o de otros), perseguir a los empleados de Stack Exchange para conseguir nuevas funcionalidades para tu sitio... Teniendo todo esto en cuenta, ¿en qué te gustaría invertir la mayor parte de su tiempo como moderador y con qué finalidad? Esboza tu idea de qué podría definirse como éxito al realizar tal labor.

Mi tiempo lo invertiría en comentar, editar preguntas para que el contenido de SO sea claro y conciso, guiando a los usuarios nuevos o a quienes tienen dudas o no saben como expresar sus dudas para de esta manera hacer crecer a la comunidad con un adecuado orden y guiá.

> ¿Qué modo de acción te parece más adecuado para un moderador ♦? ¿Usar las herramientas de moderación solo en los casos indispensables que no pueda resolver la comunidad por sí misma o ser mucho más pro-activo y tratar de actuar sobre el máximo de ámbitos del sitio para tratar que las preguntas y respuestas sean de la máxima calidad posible?
>           En resumen, ¿crees que el principal moderador de la comunidad debe ser ésta misma, o crees que la labor de moderación ♦ debe ser amplia para velar por la calidad de las publicaciones del sitio?

Como Moderador se posee una gran responsabilidad para mejorar la comunidad y como tal se debe velar por generar o mantener la mejor calidad del contenido posible en SO haciendo un uso efectivo de las herramientas a nuestra disposición.

> ¿Que harías si un usuario te acusa de abusar de tus privilegios como moderador?

La mejor opción frente a este caso es el dialogo y darle mi punto de vista el porque mi actuar y en caso de tener un error en mi criterio rectificar el mismo, para mantener el armonía y adecuada convivencia en SO.

> Si te llega un reporte y notas que se debe a una disputa entre dos o más usuarios, tomando en cuenta que los usuarios se insultan, amedrentan y se agreguen mutuamente: ¿Cuál sería tu postura? ¿Qué acciones tomarías para mediar la disputa? ¿Cómo resolverías el conflicto?

Lo primero seria el dialogo, análisis de las causas del conflicto, también recordarles que esta es una comunidad y como tal existe un código de convivencia el cual sirve para mantener y hacer crecer SO en respeto, amabilidad y contenido de calidad.

> ¿Cómo lidiarías antes los insultos o bien conversaciones que puedan tornarse turbulentas?

Los insultos no están bien vistos en ningún caso, como tal se los eliminaría para evitar tener lenguaje poco adecuado, ademas siempre recordales el código de convivencia de nuestra comunidad SO , que siempre debe existir el respeto y tolerancia mutua para que crezca nuestra comunidad.

---

Gracias por tomar tu tiempo en leer mis puntos de vista en cada una de estas preguntas y recuerden elijamos al mejor moderador para hacer crecer esta comunidad.

Answer (score 2):

Soy Mario Guiber y aquí están mis respuestas a las preguntas.

Enlace a mi [postulación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/election/2#post-248748)

> ¿Cómo tratarías a un usuario que produce una corriente estable de
>   respuestas valiosas pero que tiende a generar una cantidad grande de
>   argumentos/reportes de los comentarios?

Hablar con dicha persona en cuestión en primer lugar. Que explicase sus puntos de vista y llegar a alguna decisión con él.

> ¿Cómo enfrentarías una situación en la que otro moderador
>   cerró/eliminó/etc una pregunta que no crees que lo debía ser?

Mantener una conversación por chat directo con ese moderador y que expusiese el motivo de su decisión al realizar el cierre/eliminación de dicha pregunta.

> ¿Por qué quieres ser moderador/a?

Me gusta mucho esta comunidad, y se que puedo aportar mi granito de arena, para que todos juntos, pueda crecer poco a poco y mejorando cada día.

> Un moderador es un usuario normal al que se le dan una serie de
>   herramientas adicionales. Por tanto, las tareas de edición, comentar,
>   cerrar y abrir preguntas, etc es algo que sigue pudiendo hacer. Sin
>   embargo, también puede contactar con los usuarios de forma privada,
>   administrar etiquetas, juntar preguntas, interactuar con otros
>   moderadores (del mismo sitio o de otros), perseguir a los empleados de
>   Stack Exchange para conseguir nuevas funcionalidades para tu sitio...
>   Teniendo todo esto en cuenta, ¿en qué te gustaría invertir la mayor
>   parte de su tiempo como moderador y con qué finalidad? Esboza tu idea
>   de qué podría definirse como éxito al realizar tal labor.

Mejorar la calidad de la comunidad y sobre todo guiar a los nuevos usuarios a integrarse de lleno.

> ¿Qué modo de acción te parece más adecuado para un moderador ♦? ¿Usar
>   las herramientas de moderación solo en los casos indispensables que no
>   pueda resolver la comunidad por sí misma o ser mucho más pro-activo y
>   tratar de actuar sobre el máximo de ámbitos del sitio para tratar que
>   las preguntas y respuestas sean de la máxima calidad posible?
>   En resumen, ¿crees que el principal moderador de la comunidad debe ser
>   ésta misma, o crees que la labor de moderación ♦ debe ser amplia para
>   velar por la calidad de las publicaciones del sitio?

Ser moderador es, en cierto modo, comprometerse con la comunidad para mejorarla día a día. Comprometerse en guiar a todos los usuarios nuevos y ayudar en todo lo posible a la gente que formule sus preguntas en el sitio.

> ¿Que harías si un usuario te acusa de abusar de tus privilegios como
>   moderador?

Hablaría con dicho usuario para que explicara sus razones de porque se ha realizado tal abuso. En cualquier caso rectificar y pedir disculpas si me he equivocado.

> Si te llega un reporte y notas que se debe a una disputa entre dos o
>   más usuarios, tomando en cuenta que los usuarios se insultan,
>   amedrentan y se agreguen mutuamente: ¿Cuál sería tu postura? ¿Qué
>   acciones tomarías para mediar la disputa? ¿Cómo resolverías el
>   conflicto?

Lo resolvería hablando por separado con cada una de las partes, que explicasen sus motivos. Pensar y analizar todo lo ocurrido, y dependiendo de la situación tomar ciertas medidas.

> ¿Cómo lidiarías antes los insultos o bien conversaciones que puedan
>   tornarse turbulentas?

El lenguaje soez no es bienvenido en ninguna comunidad, ante todo respeto. Se borrarían dichos comentarios o conversaciones inapropiadas. Sobre todo hablar con ambas partes para avisar que esa actitud no es acta en este sitio.

> ¿Cómo te sienta sentirte escudriñado constantemente en el chat y en
>   Meta por las decisiones que tomes y tener que dar explicaciones sobre
>   ellas?

Espero dar siempre buenas y correctas decisiones, sin embargo, afrontaré también mis malas decisiones y daré todo explicación sobre ellas al respecto.

> Cuando hay un problema en la comunidad que no está marcado (Al menos
>   claramente) en las reglas del sitio ¿A quién le pides ayuda para saber
>   como responder a la situación?

Normalmente recurriría al chat para contactar con alguien de la comunidad con mas experiencia sobre el sitio. Le indicaría y le explicaría todo lo ocurrido para que me pueda guiar y solventar el problema.

Comment: Es bueno verte como candidato, Mario. Me encuentro con frecuencia con tus sugerencias de edición de publicaciones, que denota que quieres mejorar el sitio :) Comentas en tus respuestas que tu intención es mejorar la calidad de la comunidad. Ahora bien, esto ya puedes hacerlo (¡lo estás haciendo!) en tu rol actual. ¿Qué cosas no puedes hacer actualmente que tu rol de moderador te permitiría?

Comment: @fedorqui Muchas gracias por tu palabras. Una de las cosas seria, encaminar a los usuarios nuevos al manejo del sitio mediante un mensaje directo, indicarle (en algunos casos me ha pasado personalmente) como votar positivo y marca como aceptada la respuesta que se dan a sus dudas.

Answer (score 1):

Soy Andrés Salcedo y aquí dejo mis respuestas a las preguntas:

> ¿Cómo tratarías a un usuario que produce una corriente estable de
>   respuestas valiosas pero que tiende a generar una cantidad grande de
>   argumentos/reportes de los comentarios?

Este es el tipo de situaciones que requieren diálogo, negociar, acuerdos, entender los argumentos y los supuestos que llevan al otro a hacer las cosas de cierta forma. SO nunca ha buscado ser un lugar rígido ni violento; siempre ha evolucionado para mejorar y escuchar a los que no se sienten cómodos. Así mismo, procura comunicar de forma efectiva, así que no buscaría nada diferente a ello.

> ¿Cómo enfrentarías una situación en la que otro moderador
>   cerró/eliminó/etc una pregunta que no crees que lo debía ser?

A los ojos de los usuarios, sobre todo de los más nuevos, SO es un sitio que funciona como unidad. Someter el sitio a juicios individuales lo haría confuso; habría que preguntarle al otro moderador y dar la realimentación correspondiente para que, como si estuviéramos desarrollando código, *él sea quien arregle el bug o deje el código como está* :)

> ¿Por qué quieres ser moderador/a?

Al sitio le faltan manos. Hay épocas en las que se sugieren ediciones y pasa el tiempo límite de espera antes que llegue alguien a atenderles. En general, para la cantidad de contenido que se genera, a veces parece necesitarse ayuda. Y mi interés en este sitio es ayudar un poco más cada día.

> Un moderador es un usuario normal al que se le dan una serie de
>   herramientas adicionales. Por tanto, las tareas de edición, comentar,
>   cerrar y abrir preguntas, etc es algo que sigue pudiendo hacer. Sin
>   embargo, también puede contactar con los usuarios de forma privada,
>   administrar etiquetas, juntar preguntas, interactuar con otros
>   moderadores (del mismo sitio o de otros), perseguir a los empleados de
>   Stack Exchange para conseguir nuevas funcionalidades para tu sitio...
>   Teniendo todo esto en cuenta, ¿en qué te gustaría invertir la mayor
>   parte de su tiempo como moderador y con qué finalidad? Esboza tu idea
>   de qué podría definirse como éxito al realizar tal labor.

Siguiendo con la respuesta anterior: si mi propósito es ayudar, el indicador de éxito sería ver que los usuarios están un poco más a gusto, que encuentran más características deseables en el sitio, que les es más fácil encontrar respuesta a sus preguntas y que pueda ver que sigamos siendo más usuarios cada día. Y que yo mismo puedo preguntar y responder más y más preguntas relevantes. Que el públic en español está más familiarizado con SO en español y lo usa correctamente.

> ¿Qué modo de acción te parece más adecuado para un moderador ♦? ¿Usar
>   las herramientas de moderación solo en los casos indispensables que no
>   pueda resolver la comunidad por sí misma o ser mucho más pro-activo y
>   tratar de actuar sobre el máximo de ámbitos del sitio para tratar que
>   las preguntas y respuestas sean de la máxima calidad posible? En
>   resumen, ¿crees que el principal moderador de la comunidad debe ser
>   ésta misma, o crees que la labor de moderación ♦ debe ser amplia para
>   velar por la calidad de las publicaciones del sitio?

La moderación ♦ debe ser guía y simplemente recordar lo que todos deberíamos saber. Como tal, el ideal sería que la comunidad se autorregule y el moderador ♦ sólo resuelva situaciones en las que algo no es claro, algo es difuso o no hay negociación posible entre las partes. Entre menos se intervenga, mejor estamos.

> ¿Qué harías si un usuario te acusa de abusar de tus privilegios como
>   moderador?

Le invito a hacer el reporte en meta para que la comunidad y los otros moderadores intervengan. De paso, hacemos visible el motivo del problema y yo mismo lo leo para revisar mi proceder. Siempre hay que revaluar para mejorar.

> Si te llega un reporte y notas que se debe a una disputa entre dos o
>   más usuarios, tomando en cuenta que los usuarios se insultan,
>   amedrentan y se agreden mutuamente: ¿Cuál sería tu postura? ¿Qué
>   acciones tomarías para mediar la disputa? ¿Cómo resolverías el
>   conflicto?

La resolución del conflicto se haría de forma privada entre las partes; SO no tiene por qué sufrir con los inconvenientes entre individuos. Junto con otros moderadores, buscaría los procedimientos habituales para esas situaciones.

> ¿Cómo lidiarías antes los insultos o bien conversaciones que puedan
>   tornarse turbulentas?

Desescalando la situación. El insulto suele surgir cuando algo no se logra comunicar.

> ¿Cómo te sienta sentirte escudriñado constantemente en el chat y en
>   Meta por las decisiones que tomes y tener que dar explicaciones sobre
>   ellas?

Parte de la responsabilidad. Siempre estoy abierto a la realimentación.

> Cuando hay un problema en la comunidad que no está marcado (Al menos
>   claramente) en las reglas del sitio ¿A quién le pides ayuda para saber
>   como responder a la situación?

A otros moderadores, a la gente en meta de SO en español y de SO en inglés.

Comment: Considero que, aunque tus intenciones son buenas, te falta generar en muchas de tus preguntas una base sólida que genere confianza, pues la mayoría de tus respuestas suenan un poco diplomáticas e intentan evadir lo que se pregunta. Tienes algunas frases en las que no se siente el compromiso como moderador, no te juzgo por ello, en ocasiones lo que tenemos en nuestra mente no se aclara cuando lo pasamos a texto.

Comment: @JheymanMejia Siempre servirá la realimentación para mejorar. Gracias por tomarte el tiempo de escribirlo. Genuinamente lo agradezco.

Answer (score 0):

> ¿Cómo tratarías a un usuario que produce una corriente estable de
>   respuestas valiosas pero que tiende a generar una cantidad grande de
>   argumentos/reportes de los comentarios?

Bien, a un usuario con tal descripción le solicitaría una justificación técnica en caso de que su reporte tenga relación al área técnica o una justificación muy bien estructurada del por que de su reporte, preferiblemente con base a otras situaciones similares ya tratadas y vistas, esto también lo considero relevante por que así conozco la actividad y atención que este usuario brinda al sitio.

> ¿Cómo enfrentarías una situación en la que otro moderador
>   cerró/eliminó/etc una pregunta que no crees que lo debía ser?

Considero que el caso en cuestión tendría ser evaluado entre el moderador que realizó tal acción y yo en este caso, siempre con argumentos claros y basado preferiblemente en conocimientos técnicos, esto define quien tiene la razón entre ambos moderadores, pero también buscando un punto medio entre ambas opiniones, con esto me refiero a que podría ser modificada tal pregunta de forma que pueda ser aceptada teniendo en cuenta también la relevancia del tema planteado en la misma y cuanto podría ayudar a la comunidad que la misma se mantenga activa en el sitio.

> ¿Por qué quieres ser moderador/a?

Tengo especial interés en ser moderador por que me gusta ayudar a personas que quieran ponerle ganas a su aprendizaje y al sitio, me pongo en el lugar de ellos por que cuando todos comenzamos de alguna forma nos gusta se orientados por usuarios que tengan mas conocimiento. Me gustaría ser moderador, buscando dar motivación a otros usuarios a seguir mejorando.

> Un moderador es un usuario normal al que se le dan una serie de
>   herramientas adicionales. Por tanto, las tareas de edición, comentar,
>   cerrar y abrir preguntas, etc es algo que sigue pudiendo hacer. Sin
>   embargo, también puede contactar con los usuarios de forma privada,
>   administrar etiquetas, juntar preguntas, interactuar con otros
>   moderadores (del mismo sitio o de otros), perseguir a los empleados de
>   Stack Exchange para conseguir nuevas funcionalidades para tu sitio...
>
> Teniendo todo esto en cuenta, ¿en qué te gustaría invertir la mayor
>   parte de su tiempo como moderador y con qué finalidad? Esboza tu idea
>   de qué podría definirse como éxito al realizar tal labor.

Me gustaría invertir mi tiempo en la revisión de los planteamientos de las preguntas siempre intentado que estas sean mas claras a nivel de redacción y de ideas plasmadas en la misma, comentar de ser necesario siempre con la intención de buscar una mejora en las preguntas o respuestas y cerrar o abrir según sea necesario, esto haciendo especial énfasis en que el usuario que haga la pregunta o respuesta ponga interés en aceptar mejoras sugeridas. Esto en base a que en ocasiones por opinión personal me ha costado un poco entender los planteamientos que se hacen, debido a que no todos tienen un amplio conocimiento y se les dificulta entenderlas. Siempre buscando que sean mas sencillas de leer, también se entiende que para experimentados pueda ser tedioso leer algo tan explicito en ocasiones por muy sencillo que sea el tema, pero la verdad no todos los usuarios tienen amplios conocimientos como ya mencione, todos comenzamos desde abajo, por decirlo de alguna forma.

> ¿Qué modo de acción te parece más adecuado para un moderador ♦? ¿Usar
>   las herramientas de moderación solo en los casos indispensables que no
>   pueda resolver la comunidad por sí misma o ser mucho más pro-activo y
>   tratar de actuar sobre el máximo de ámbitos del sitio para tratar que
>   las preguntas y respuestas sean de la máxima calidad posible?
>
> En resumen, ¿crees que el principal moderador de la comunidad debe ser
>   ésta misma, o crees que la labor de moderación ♦ debe ser amplia para
>   velar por la calidad de las publicaciones del sitio?

Pienso que las labores de un moderador es mejorar lo mas posible las publicaciones del sitio, pero tampoco que hagan todo el trabajo cuando de eso se trata el sitio, "una comunidad", se entiende que tiene muchas mas herramientas para hacer del sitio mejor, mas legible y mas agradable para todos los usuarios, una labor muy ardua en opinión personal, pero también es importante la interacción y preocupación de la comunidad por mejorar el sitio en lo que puedan para ellos mismos o para otros usuarios. Podría decir que el sitio se compone de 50 y 50, ambas partes deben contribuir para un bien común.

> ¿Qué harías si un usuario te acusa de abusar de tus privilegios como
>   moderador?

Importante, si un usuario realiza tal acción le solicitaría las razones explicitas del por que su reclamo hacia mi, con bases en sus argumentos, y en caso que el mismo tenga la razón y que estoy en un error por una o múltiples cosas, lo aceptaría, pero en caso opuesto, le daría mis argumentos, de igual forma, claros y basados en las normas del sitio y si lo requiere referencias de decisiones similares hechas en el pasado, dándole una respuesta firme en mi defensa esperando la acepte lo mejor posible y terminando el tema de esa forma.

> Si te llega un reporte y notas que se debe a una disputa entre dos o
>   más usuarios, tomando en cuenta que los usuarios se insultan,
>   amedrentan y se agreden mutuamente: ¿Cuál sería tu postura? ¿Qué
>   acciones tomarías para mediar la disputa? ¿Cómo resolverías el
>   conflicto?

Primero leería el inicio de la disputa, asumiendo que comenzó por diferencia de opiniones acerca de un tema, importante también vería la postura de cada usuario desde un comienzo viendo quien la comenzó, cabe destacar que, siempre una de 2 personas siempre comienza, esta en la otra continuarla, de acorde a esto evaluaría la situación dependiendo de hasta que punto haya llegado cada usuario y aplicando las amonestaciones respectivas de ser necesario.

> ¿Cómo lidiarías antes los insultos o bien conversaciones que puedan
>   tornarse turbulentas?

Pienso que desde el momento que comienzan a insultarse unos a otros, se debe interceder, esto daña el sitio. Como mencione anteriormente es necesario evaluar que usuario comienza a insultar y también vería, si este usuario ha repetido estas acciones conflictivas en ocasiones pasadas. Evitando en lo posible que vuelva a ocurrir de nuevo en caso de que este usuario sea frecuentemente ofensivo. En otro el otro caso, que sea primera vez para ambos, es mejor interceder de forma neutral, para también evitar represalias contra el moderador que actúe en esta disputa.

> ¿Cómo te sienta sentirte escudriñado constantemente en el chat y en
>   Meta por las decisiones que tomes y tener que dar explicaciones sobre
>   ellas?

Pienso que las cosas no se tratan de ver lo malo que realizo otra persona, y la forma que lo hizo, siempre intentando quedar bien con otros destruyendo a un compañero, se supone que si todos trabajan para un bien común, no se debe criticar de forma negativa, sino apoyar y dar criticas constructivas para evitar que incurra en acciones similares en un futuro. Nada se logra con verle lo malo siempre a otro, quizás desde el punto de vista de uno como usuario seria interpretada como constante acoso, si siempre son criticas negativas. Aunque también es importante verlo desde otro punto de vista, todo lo malo tiene algo bueno, a esto se le puede llamar experiencia.

> Cuando hay un problema en la comunidad que no está marcado (Al menos
>   claramente) en las reglas del sitio ¿A quién le pides ayuda para saber
>   como responder a la situación?

Siendo moderador, trataria el tema con otros moderadores, quien mas que todo el grupo evaluando esta situacion si no es un problema claramente marcado para mejorar las reglas del sitio. Entre mas se mejore el sitio para futuro mucho mejor.

Comment: ¡Buenas respuestas, Blitz, y gracias por presentarte! ¿Qué cosas que no puedes hacer actualmente crees que podrías hacer como moderador? Porque de las que detallas, creo que casi todas se centrarían en comentar y editar para mejorar la calidad de las publicaciones. ¡Gracias!

Comment: Me gusta e interesa lo de poder contactarme con otros usuarios y moderadores,  esto por que?,  siento que entre más pueda ayudar mucho mejor, de poder evitar algún problema con un usuario problemático o de alguna discusión hablarlo con él directamente, en este caso siento que es mejor hablarlo por privado y evitar hacerlo público, no considero que toda una comunidad vea un problema de la nada y de pie para que otros usuarios repitan estas conductas, en caso que un usuario incurra repetidamente en malas ediciones y malos planteamientos, de ser posible ayudarlos mas directamente.

Comment: Y contactarme con otros moderadores, siempre me ha gustado estar rodeado de personas más sabías que yo, que puedan enseñarme de todo un poco y pues aprender de ellos lo más posible, y tener la oportunidad de interactuar más directamente con estas personas sería muy interesante.