# ¿Existe alguna forma de ver quién se va presentando a las elecciones?

Tags: soporte, página-de-elecciones

En la [página de Elección de Moderador](https://es.stackoverflow.com/election) van apareciendo postulaciones. Ahora uno, ahora otro. Ahora uno que se había postulado se retira... en fin, lo que viene siendo lo normal cuando hay elecciones.

Yo me voy enterando de las nuevas postulaciones a medida que van contestando en [2019 Elección de Moderador - Cuestionario](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4015/83), pero es incompleto porque ni es obligatorio responderlas, ni lo hacen en el mismo momento de presentarse.

Por eso me pregunto: ¿existe alguna manera de ver las actualizaciones en la página de elecciones? Algo así como la línea de tiempo de una publicación ([de esta pregunta por ejemplo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/4034/timeline)). O incluso un RSS.

Comment: Ninguna que yo conozca, lamentablemente...