# ¿Un Boletín de noticias para la comunidad?

Tags: discusión, característica-nueva

Hace algunos días que se planteó la problemática del poco nivel de votos que tenemos en nuestra comunidad (**[¿Ya conseguiste tu medalla Vox Populi?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4188/ya-conseguiste-tu-medalla-vox-populi)**), y relacionado a esto, también hablamos de los problemas con el voto por la reputación (**[No votemos positivamente por la reputación, votemos el contenido!](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4192/no-votemos-positivamente-por-la-reputaci%c3%b3n-votemos-el-contenido)**). Más, otros temas que se vienen hablando hace tiempo, muchos de estos puntos, pienso yo, **son estratégicos para el crecimiento ordenado del sitio**. Sin embargo, me parece, hay una falta de visibilización de estos contenidos a nivel comunidad.

#### ¿Quiénes y cómo se enteran de estos temas?

- Los que leen o participan en meta
- Los que eventualmente entran al chat y leen estas discusiones
- Aquellos a los que eventualmente, en algún comentario se los va "orientando"

En mi opinión (la cual es totalmente empírica), ésta forma de distribuir la "cultura" de SOes es insuficiente. Creo que debemos buscar llegar al grueso de la comunidad,  **distribuir la cultura de Soes** y en ese sentido, hablando con @gbianchi le plantee la idea de:

### Un **[newsletter](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolet%C3%ADn_informativo)** o **Boletín informativo**

Con algunas características:

- Que no sea tan frecuente como para que sea considerado "spam" (¿mensual/bimestral tal vez?)
- Concreto, corto y atractivo
- Dónde podamos transmitir las ideas importantes y estratégicas que se discutan en meta.
- Dónde podamos encarar acciones de "educación" apuntadas a la comunidad en general
- Obviamente dentro del marco de las políticas de notificación por mail que implementa SO en general
- Sin duda, con un contenido bien elaborado y seguramente con el ok del CM

---

**Atención**: Lo que sigue es totalmente especulativo, solo busca ser un disparador de ideas.

#### ¿Cómo presentar este Boletín de noticias?

Esta es la parte, para mí más delicada, hay que lograr que el usuario general, lo lea, la palabra, la dije antes: **Atractivo**, un boletín de noticias que dé gusto leer, si mal no recuerdo hubo uno hace un tiempo atrás. La idea es educar pero que no se note como "bajada de línea". No soy el más apropiado para definir esto, pero se me ocurre contenido que pudiera integrarse en este boletín para hacerlo atractivo, algunas ideas apuntan a la idea original, **distribuir la cultura de Soes** y otras más a lo de hacerlo atractivo:

- **La "caliente" discusión en Meta de este mes**. ¿Que problemas enfrenta la comunidad? ¿Qué se dijo? ¿Se llego a un consenso?, ¿Que vamos a hacer de ahora en más? ¿Que espera la comunidad de tí? etc.
- **La pregunta del mes**. Tomar una pregunta bien formulada, de un usuario nuevo, y describir que la hace una buena pregunta.
- **Breves entrevistas a los moderadores o usuarios en general**. ¿Que hacen? ¿De dónde son? ¿Por qué están en Soes?
- **Números y estadísticas**. A mí personalmente me atraen los números, por lo que números bien generales y concretos del sitio, me resultan atractivos. Cantidad de preguntas y respuestas del mes, Ratio porcentual. Cantidad promedio de votos por pregunta. Top  "usuarios nuevos" votantes, etc.

Comment: ¿Quién imaginas que haría el trabajo que haya que hacer?

Comment: @Rubén, creo que la comunidad en meta puede aportar temas a este "newsletter" o al menos votar propuestas, pero sin duda me parece, debería haber una "mesa chica", imagino que los moderadores electos serían los más adecuados, y seguramente la decisión final del CM.

Comment: Quizás los moderadores electos deberán participar pero creo que la "mesa chica" debería incluir más miembros regulares que moderadores electos.

Comment: Si, puede ser, y seguramente sería positivo, el tema con los moderadores electos, es que, es una categoría que no es discutible, si agregamos más usuarios ya el limite de quiénes si y quiénes no, es más gris.

Comment: En cuanto a poner límites de quienes sí, y quienes no, como me dijo un compañero hace tiempo, *cuando lleguemos a ese río veremos como lo cruzamos*. Aparte de los votos, todavía nadie más se ha sumado a la discusión y nadie ha dicho "yo" (me hago/haría cargo de esto o aquello).

Comment: Patricio ¿diste un vistazo al boletín que sale actualmente? En el enlace que da @Rubén https://stackexchange.com/newsletters si buscas puedes ver el último "ejemplar". Creo que cubre bastante de lo que pides. La parte de números la llevaba Juan hace unos años en el blog, pero se paró ([ejemplo](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/01/05/el-estado-de-stack-overflow-en-espanol-diciembre-2017/)).

Comment: @fedorqui, si, lo estuve viendo. Me parece que podría ser un buen medio adicional para extender estos temas que charlamos en meta, habría que ver de que forma se elabora el contenido y si efectivamente podemos incorporar estos contenidos al newsletter.

Answer (score 3):

**[Ya existe un blog oficial](https://stackoverflow.blog/tags/international/espanol/)** con información y contenido como el que sugieres. Cuando @JuanM era el CM del sitio, realizó algunas entradas al blog.

Me encantaba ver temas como:

- Las 5 preguntas más visitadas del mes
- Los usuarios que hicieran la más grande contribución de preguntas del mes
- La pregunta más compartida del mes

Otros temas, de igual manera interesantes, eran algunas métricas y noticias; como cuando se dio la primer elección de moderadores después de la graduación del sitio.

Ojalá se retome, y sea más constante.

---

A modo de propuesta, podríamos crear nuestro propio newsletter aquí en Meta (en caso de que sea muy complicado retomar el blog oficial), tomando en cuenta que tenemos acceso al [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com), crear nuestros propios queries ([que podemos guardar](https://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/1070135)) y obtener básicamente lo que queramos. Por ejemplo:

## Las 10 preguntas con más vistas durante lo que va del mes de junio:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+--------------------+
| Título                                                                                                      | Vistas | Usuario            |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+--------------------+
| Utilizar valor devuelto por metodo en otro metodo                                                           | 320    | Joaquin Vargas     |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+--------------------+
| ¿Cómo eliminar los array session variables de múltiples pasos de un wizard?                                 | 282    | J. Mick            |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+--------------------+
| ERROR instalacion de proyecto angular                                                                       | 274    | Juanperez          |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+--------------------+
| Eliminar y actualizar un modelo relacionado en php laravel                                                  | 186    | Asdrubal Hernandez |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+--------------------+
| DeprecatedWarning (cb.iterable) al usar Networkx                                                            | 165    | 3ngineer2k8        |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+--------------------+
| Seleccion entre fechas mysql                                                                                | 123    | Diego Avila        |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+--------------------+
| ¿Cómo contar elementos repetidos en un array?                                                               | 113    | mhplur             |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+--------------------+
| ¿Porqué los enlaces <link rel="stylesheet" ......> en partes de mi página web cambian el estilo del header? | 108    | Jack More          |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+--------------------+
| Validar caracteres, mayúsculas, minúsculas y caracteres numéricos y otros, para una contraseña en C# .NET   | 95     | Jhohan David       |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+--------------------+
| Envío de correo con copia PHP                                                                               | 95     | Carlos             |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------+--------------------+
```

*<sup>Información obtenida el día 26 de junio a las 05:00 a.m. (GTM)</sup>*

En coordinación con Nicolas, se podrían planear algunos Webcast, entrevistas, o incluso podríamos poner a votación la pregunta caliente de Meta (me encantó esta propuesta):

## La "caliente" discusión en Meta de este mes (vote por su preferida):

- Opción A: El ban por decir malas palabras en el chat
- Opción B: Mercadopago se cuelga de Stackoverflow en Español
- Opción C: Tabuladores contra espacios

No sé, un poco de humor tampoco caería nada mal.

Me apunto para contribuir al respecto y seguir dando algunas sugerencias.

Comment: No quieres entrar en la guerra de Tabuladores contra espacios. No quieres.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster tabuladores forever!

Comment: Absolutamente, recuerdo el Blog, me resultaba muy atractivo. Esa básicamente es la idea general, investigar otras formas de comunicación con la comunidad, para poder extender lo que llamo la "cultura" del sitio. Sin la (A) es un "gancho" terrible.

Comment: Seria interesante ver si ese Blog sigue de alguna manera activo y que tán posibles sería que la comunidad de meta pueda incorporar contenido en él. Lo de un publicación en meta, me parece más concreto e igualmente interesante.

Comment: Asombroso la primera pregunta que sale es una que esta cerrada y con un voto negativo!

Answer (score 0):

Ya existen varios boletines en Stack Exchange

1. Boletín de comunidad (en inglés "community bulletin", el recuadro que se muestra en el panel derecho, que usualmente incluye Destacado en Meta y Discusiones populares en meta)
2. Los boletines generados automáticamente que se envían por correo electrónico (en inglés "newsletter") y a los que uno se puede suscribir desde https://stackexchange.com/newsletters y otros lados

Sobre el primero todavía no lo aprovechamos al máximo pero esto es debido a que aún no usamos (al menos no he visto que lo hagamos) la característica *eventos de comunidad*. Según entiendo los *eventos de comunidad* del boletín de comunidad es una característica que sólo los moderadores diamantados pueden editar y que la documentación de la misma está en el centro de ayuda *sólo para los ojos* de los moderadores diamantados. Los miembros regulares de la comunidad que quieran que se use esta característica, deberán solicitarlo a los moderadores diamantados por los canales habituales.

Sobre el segundo, ... seguiré leyendo

Referencias

- [Redesigned community bulletin](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/234453/289691)
- [What is the weekly newsletter? Who composes them?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/121630/289691)
- [We have meetups, events, community-events, conferences tags. Are all the same?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316788/289691)

Comment: Es cierto, pero me parece que los de nuestra comunidad hace rato que no salen. ¿puede ser? por otro lado, desconozco como se arman estos boletines, ¿puede la comunidad aportar a los mismos?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho No estoy del todo seguro. Según la segunda referencia ( *What is the weekly newsletter? Who composes them?*) se pueden incluir anuncios importantes como elecciones

Comment: Claro, pero no hay uno dedicado a nuestra comunidad en particular...

Comment: @gbianchi ¿Dónde estás mirando? Yo si lo veo en https://stackexchange.com/newsletters. [Vista previa](https://es.stackoverflow.com/newsletter/preview)

Comment: si., pero eso es un listado de preguntas del sitio. Creo que un boletin con novedades mas particulares del sitio seria algo mejor...

Comment: @gbianchi Por favor agrega una respuesta para explicar a que te refieres y cómo se complementa o sería mejor que lo que ya existe.

Comment: Si si.. espera que estamos atacando varios frentes al mismo tiempo.. pero si.. ya pondre una respuesta... tambien tenemos que ver que se puede hacer con los CM...

Comment: Está bien, me espero :P

Answer (score 0):

> **Breves entrevistas a los moderadores o usuarios en general**. ¿Que hacen? ¿De dónde son? ¿Por qué están en Soes?

Juan hace tiempo condujo webcasts

- [Webcasts 2016 - ¿cómo y por qué? -- ¡Fechas!](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/419/65)
- [Webcasts 2017 - ¿cómo y por qué? — ¡Fechas!](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1337/65)

También tenemos los cuestionarios para los que se desean postular para ser moderador electo

- [2019 Elección de Moderador - Cuestionario](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4015/65)
- [2017 Elección de Moderador - Cuestionario](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2478/65)

Para no meternos en hacer nuevas entrevistas, al menos hasta que alguien se anime a hacerlas, se podría toma extractos.

También está el podcast en inglés, que podría hacerse un resumen en español.